# What are queues in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I found the jQuery.com document on `queue()`/`dequeue()` is too simple to understand. What exactly are queues in jQuery? How should I use them?

Comment: A good example of solving a problem with a queue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230333/how-to-avoid-callback-chains/5230395#5230395

Answer (score 491):

### The uses of jQuery [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)

[Queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) in jQuery are used for animations.  You can use them for any purpose you like.  They are an **array of functions** stored on a per element basis, using [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data).  They are First-In-First-Out (FIFO).  You can add a function to the queue by calling [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue), and you remove (by calling) the functions using [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue).

To understand the internal jQuery queue functions, [reading the source](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js) and looking at examples helps me out tremendously.  One of the best examples of a queue function I've seen is [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay):

```
$.fn.delay = function( time, type ) {
  time = jQuery.fx ? jQuery.fx.speeds[time] || time : time;
  type = type || "fx";

  return this.queue( type, function() {
    var elem = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
    }, time );
  });
};
```

### The default queue - `fx`

The default queue in jQuery is `fx`.  The default queue has some special properties that are not shared with other queues.

1. **Auto Start:** When calling `$(elem).queue(function(){});` the `fx` queue will automatically `dequeue` the next function and run it if the queue hasn't started.
2. **'inprogress' sentinel:** Whenever you `dequeue()` a function from the `fx` queue, it will `unshift()` (push into the first location of the array) the string `"inprogress"` - which flags that the queue is currently being run.
3. **It's the default!** The `fx` queue is used by `.animate()` and all functions that call it by default.

**NOTE:** If you are using a custom queue, you must manually `.dequeue()` the functions, they will not auto start!

### Retrieving/Setting the queue

You can retrieve a reference to a jQuery queue by calling `.queue()` without a function argument.  You can use the method if you want to see how many items are in the queue.  You can use `push`, `pop`, `unshift`, `shift` to manipulate the queue in place.  You can replace the entire queue by passing an array to the `.queue()` function.

**Quick Examples:**

```
// lets assume $elem is a jQuery object that points to some element we are animating.
var queue = $elem.queue();
// remove the last function from the animation queue.
var lastFunc = queue.pop(); 
// insert it at the beginning:    
queue.unshift(lastFunc);
// replace queue with the first three items in the queue
$elem.queue(queue.slice(0,3));
```

### An animation (`fx`) queue example:

[Run example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evRG5/3/embedded/result)

```
$(function() {
    // lets do something with google maps:
    var $map = $("#map_canvas");
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {zoom: 8, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var map = new google.maps.Map($map[0], myOptions);
    var resized = function() {
        // simple animation callback - let maps know we resized
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    };

    // wait 2 seconds
    $map.delay(2000);
    // resize the div:
    $map.animate({
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        marginLeft: 250,
        marginTop:250
    }, resized);
    // geocode something
    $map.queue(function(next) {
        // find stackoverflow's whois address:
      geocoder.geocode({'address': '55 Broadway New York NY 10006'},handleResponse);

      function handleResponse(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var location = results[0].geometry.location;
              map.setZoom(13);
              map.setCenter(location);
              new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: location });
          }
          // geocoder result returned, continue with animations:
          next();
      }
    });
    // after we find stack overflow, wait 3 more seconds
    $map.delay(3000);
    // and resize the map again
    $map.animate({
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        marginLeft:0,
        marginTop: 0
    }, resized);
});
```

### Another custom queue example

[Run example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkBJk/embedded/result)

```
var theQueue = $({}); // jQuery on an empty object - a perfect queue holder

$.each([1,2,3],function(i, num) {
  // lets add some really simple functions to a queue:
  theQueue.queue('alerts', function(next) { 
    // show something, and if they hit "yes", run the next function.
    if (confirm('index:'+i+' = '+num+'\nRun the next function?')) {
      next();
    }
  }); 
});

// create a button to run the queue:
$("<button>", {
  text: 'Run Queue', 
  click: function() { 
    theQueue.dequeue('alerts'); 
  }
}).appendTo('body');

// create a button to show the length:
$("<button>", {
  text: 'Show Length', 
  click: function() { 
    alert(theQueue.queue('alerts').length); 
  }
}).appendTo('body');
```

### Queueing Ajax Calls:

I developed an [`$.ajaxQueue()`](http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/) plugin that uses the [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred), [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue), and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) to also pass back a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) that is resolved when the request completes. Another version of `$.ajaxQueue` that still works in 1.4 is posted on my answer to [Sequencing Ajax Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034874/sequencing-ajax-requests/3035268#3035268)

```
/*
* jQuery.ajaxQueue - A queue for ajax requests
* 
* (c) 2011 Corey Frang
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*
* Requires jQuery 1.5+
*/ 
(function($) {

// jQuery on an empty object, we are going to use this as our Queue
var ajaxQueue = $({});

$.ajaxQueue = function( ajaxOpts ) {
    var jqXHR,
        dfd = $.Deferred(),
        promise = dfd.promise();

    // queue our ajax request
    ajaxQueue.queue( doRequest );

    // add the abort method
    promise.abort = function( statusText ) {

        // proxy abort to the jqXHR if it is active
        if ( jqXHR ) {
            return jqXHR.abort( statusText );
        }

        // if there wasn't already a jqXHR we need to remove from queue
        var queue = ajaxQueue.queue(),
            index = $.inArray( doRequest, queue );

        if ( index > -1 ) {
            queue.splice( index, 1 );
        }

        // and then reject the deferred
        dfd.rejectWith( ajaxOpts.context || ajaxOpts,
            [ promise, statusText, "" ] );

        return promise;
    };

    // run the actual query
    function doRequest( next ) {
        jqXHR = $.ajax( ajaxOpts )
            .done( dfd.resolve )
            .fail( dfd.reject )
            .then( next, next );
    }

    return promise;
};

})(jQuery);
```

---

*I have now added this as an article on [learn.jquery.com](http://learn.jquery.com/effects/uses-of-queue-and-dequeue/), there are other great articles on that site about queues, go look.*

Comment: +1. I'm working on a jQuery-based user script that needs to connect to a PHP script as if it were another PHP script running on the client -- one HTTP request/other operation at a time, so this will definitely be helpful. Just a question: jQuery requires that queues be attached to objects, right? So which object should I use? `$(window)`?

Comment: @idealmachine - As seen in the Ajax Queue example, you can actually attach queue events to an empty object: `$({})`

Comment: This summary is incredibly useful. I just finished building a lazy loader for delaying the request for heavy content that's below the bottom of the screen until it's scrolled into view.  Using jQuery's queue() made those Ajax requests very smooth (even if you jump straight to the bottom of the page).  Thanks!

Comment: It's nice to find out your still updating this for newer versions of jQuery. +1 :)

Comment: To add one thing for those just learning queues and promises etc - in the ajaxQueue example, the call to $.ajaxQueue() to which you put you ajax request you wish to queue inside the () will return a promise.  The way you wait until the queue is empty is via promise.done(function(){ alert("done")});.  Took me an hr to find this, so hope this helps someone else save their hr!

Comment: Users - note the promises ajax queue code is quite bad. It's probably just there to illustrate something.

Comment: Quite bad? Reasoning please? Maybe people actually use this code :)

Comment: @gnarf : the link to the jsfiddle for "An animation (fx) queue example" is broken

Answer (score 43):

To understand queue method, you have to understand how jQuery does animation. If you write multiple animate method calls one after the other, jQuery creates an 'internal' queue and adds these method calls to it. Then it runs those animate calls one by one.

Consider following code.

```
function nonStopAnimation()
{
    //These multiple animate calls are queued to run one after
    //the other by jQuery.
    //This is the reason that nonStopAnimation method will return immeidately
    //after queuing these calls. 
    $('#box').animate({ left: '+=500'}, 4000);
    $('#box').animate({ top: '+=500'}, 4000);
    $('#box').animate({ left: '-=500'}, 4000);

    //By calling the same function at the end of last animation, we can
    //create non stop animation. 
    $('#box').animate({ top: '-=500'}, 4000 , nonStopAnimation);
}
```

The 'queue'/'dequeue' method gives you control over this 'animation queue'.

By default the animation queue is named 'fx'. I have created a sample page here which has various examples which will illustrate how the queue method could be used.

http://jsbin.com/zoluge/1/edit?html,output

Code for above sample page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nonStopAnimation').click(nonStopAnimation);

    $('#stopAnimationQueue').click(function() {
        //By default all animation for particular 'selector'
        //are queued in queue named 'fx'.
        //By clearning that queue, you can stop the animation.
        $('#box').queue('fx', []);
    });

    $('#addAnimation').click(function() {
        $('#box').queue(function() {
            $(this).animate({ height : '-=25'}, 2000);
            //De-queue our newly queued function so that queues
            //can keep running.
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });

    $('#stopAnimation').click(function() {
        $('#box').stop();
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#currentQueueLength').html(
         'Current Animation Queue Length for #box ' + 
          $('#box').queue('fx').length
        );
    }, 2000);
});

function nonStopAnimation()
{
    //These multiple animate calls are queued to run one after
    //the other by jQuery.
    $('#box').animate({ left: '+=500'}, 4000);
    $('#box').animate({ top: '+=500'}, 4000);
    $('#box').animate({ left: '-=500'}, 4000);
    $('#box').animate({ top: '-=500'}, 4000, nonStopAnimation);
}
```

Now you may ask, why should I bother with this queue? Normally, you wont. But if you have a complicated animation sequence which you want to control, then queue/dequeue methods are your friend.

Also see this interesting conversation on jQuery group about creating a complicated animation sequence.

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/b398ad505a9b0512/f4f3e841eab5f5a2?lnk=gst

Demo of the animation:

http://www.exfer.net/test/jquery/tabslide/

Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 20):

## Multiple objects animation in a queue

Here is a simple example of multiple objects animation in a queue.

Jquery alow us to make queue over only one object. But within animation function we can access other objects. In this example we build our queue over #q object while animating #box1 and #box2 objects.

Think of queue as a array of functions. So you can manipulate queue as a array.  You can use push, pop, unshift, shift to manipulate the queue. In this example we remove the last function from the animation queue and insert it at the beginning.

When we are done, we start animation queue by dequeue() function.

[See at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enf644/6bX28/2/)

html:

```
  <button id="show">Start Animation Queue</button>
  <p></p>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="q"></div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){

 $('#q').queue('chain',function(next){  
      $("#box2").show("slow", next);
  });


  $('#q').queue('chain',function(next){  
      $('#box1').animate(
          {left: 60}, {duration:1000, queue:false, complete: next}
      )
  });    


  $('#q').queue('chain',function(next){  
      $("#box1").animate({top:'200'},1500, next);
  });


  $('#q').queue('chain',function(next){  
      $("#box2").animate({top:'200'},1500, next);
  });


  $('#q').queue('chain',function(next){  
      $("#box2").animate({left:'200'},1500, next);
  });

  //notice that show effect comes last
  $('#q').queue('chain',function(next){  
      $("#box1").show("slow", next);
  });

});

$("#show").click(function () {
    $("p").text("Queue length is: " + $('#q').queue("chain").length);

    // remove the last function from the animation queue.
    var lastFunc = $('#q').queue("chain").pop();
    // insert it at the beginning:    
    $('#q').queue("chain").unshift(lastFunc);

    //start animation queue
    $('#q').dequeue('chain');
});
```

css:

```
        #box1 { margin:3px; width:40px; height:40px;
                position:absolute; left:10px; top:60px; 
                background:green; display: none; }
        #box2 { margin:3px; width:40px; height:40px;
                position:absolute; left:100px; top:60px; 
                background:red; display: none; }
        p { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 15):

It allows you to queue up animations... for example, instead of this

```
$('#my-element').animate( { opacity: 0.2, width: '100px' }, 2000);
```

Which fades the element and makes the width 100 px **at the same time**. Using the queue allows you to stage the animations. So one finishes after the other.

```
$("#show").click(function () {
    var n = $("div").queue("fx");
    $("span").text("Queue length is: " + n.length);
});

function runIt() {
    $("div").show("slow");
    $("div").animate({left:'+=200'},2000);
    $("div").slideToggle(1000);
    $("div").slideToggle("fast");
    $("div").animate({left:'-=200'},1500);
    $("div").hide("slow");
    $("div").show(1200);
    $("div").slideUp("normal", runIt);
}
runIt();
```

Example from http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/queue

Comment: This is not correct. When you have multiple 'animate' calls, jQuery puts them in a queue to execute them one by one. Using the queue method, now you can access that queue and manipulate it, if need be.

Comment: @SolutionYogi - Please edit my answer if you feel it to be incorrect - the answer is CW'd and you have enough rep.

Answer (score 8):

This thread helped me a lot with my problem, but I've used $.queue in a different way and thought I would post what I came up with here. What I needed was a sequence of events (frames) to be triggered, but the sequence to be built dynamically. I have a variable number of placeholders, each of which should contain an animated sequence of images. The data is held in an array of arrays, so I loop through the arrays to build each sequence for each of the placeholders like this:

```
/* create an empty queue */
var theQueue = $({});
/* loop through the data array */
for (var i = 0; i < ph.length; i++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < ph[i].length; l++) {
        /* create a function which swaps an image, and calls the next function in the queue */
        theQueue.queue("anim", new Function("cb", "$('ph_"+i+"' img').attr('src', '/images/"+i+"/"+l+".png');cb();"));
        /* set the animation speed */
        theQueue.delay(200,'anim');
    }
}
/* start the animation */
theQueue.dequeue('anim');
```

This is a simplified version of the script I have arrived at, but should show the principle - when a function is added to the queue, it is added using the Function constructor - this way the function can be written dynamically using variables from the loop(s). Note the way the function is passed the argument for the next() call, and this is invoked at the end. The function in this case has no time dependency (it doesn't use $.fadeIn or anything like that), so I stagger the frames using $.delay.

Comment: $.queue is basically a push to an array stored in $.data, which is why you have to manually tell it to execute the next function with the cb(); Is my understanding correct?