# jQuery Dropdown queue buildup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a drop down with jQuery that can be seen here by clicking the **Preview** button on top:

```
var open_submenu = null;

$(function(){
  $('.dropdown').hover(function(){

    // hide all previous submenus and fix queue buildup problem
    $('.sublinks').stop(false, true).hide();

    // get corresponding submenus
    var submenu = $(this).parent().next();

    $(this).parent().nextAll().stop();

    $(submenu).css({
      top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 4 + 'px',
      left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
      zIndex:10000
    });

    // show the submenu
    $(submenu).stop().slideDown(300);

    open_submenu = submenu;

    submenu.hover(function(){}, function(){
      $(this).slideUp(300);
    });
  }, function(){});
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ubire3/edit

It works fine except for one problem. When I hover over the main hover links (blue ones) quickly eg. going horizontally **quickly** hovering each top menu, the some submenus don't close. How do I make it so that even if I hover fast over them all other submenus are closed?

### Edit

I saw this useful link using some ways to avoid this, but having bit of problems, how to apply that in my case.

[What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great, finally I solved the problem myself:

All I did was to modify the line:

```
$('.sublinks').hide();
```

to

```
$('.sublinks').stop(false, true).hide();
```

The `stop` stopped animations for previous sub-menus. You can see the documentation of it on the [jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

See fixed version here:

http://jsbin.com/ubire3/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it here**: http://jsbin.com/ubire3/3

I don't know why my changes were not reflected @ above link

See it [here](http://jsbin.com/ubire3/6)

i am not using `stop` method

Comment: @Rakesh: Thanks but the problem is still there, just try hovering from Menu One to Menu Five **quickly**, the submenues of previous heading do not close. Also i don't see any change in the code, wonder what you changed there?