# Mechanism of Recursive Callbacks

Tags: javascript, recursion, callback

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/9/

```
var s = $('#shake');
var randomTran = function (flag) {
    flag = flag || 0;
    if (flag < 6) {
        var rh = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
            rv = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
        s.transit({x: rh,y: rv}, 50, randomTran.bind(this, ++flag))
    };
};
randomTran();
s.transit({x: 0,y: 0});
```

I'm trying to make the element shake for a few seconds and then return to its original position. But it doesn't work as I expected, the problem is with the callback function. According to this question: [If a jQuery function calls itself in its completion callback, is that a recursive danger to the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705345/if-a-jquery-function-calls-itself-in-its-completion-callback-is-that-a-recursiv), it seems that while callback is still looping, the codes that come after the callback function are also being executed. 
So how to achieve my goal, other than setting a timeout? And where can I find a more detailed explanation about this mechanism?

Comment: there's no callback in your function, and it runs simultaneously because randomtran runs asynchronously

Comment: Doesn't `.transit` *use* a timeout already?

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is working as expected, and the animations are queued (they even would be queued if `.transit()` was called multiple times repeatedly, as the plugin uses jQuery's internal animation queue). The only thing is that 50 milliseconds for a animation on up to 5 pixels are much too fast. I've increased the time and printed the counter [in this revision of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/11/).

> it seems that while callback is still looping, the codes that come after the callback function are also being executed.

There is no "looping callback". The callback is *passed* to the function which `return`s *before* the callback is *called* - and the code that called `.transit()` continues (which, in your case, is the closing `}` brace from the if, the end of the `randomTran()` call, and the `s.transit({x: 0,y: 0});` initialisation.

Once this code has finished executing, other code can be executed - asynchronously. The callback that was stored somewhere is now - in the future, 50ms after the `transit()` call - being called; does start another transition, does schedule another callback, and ends.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, so to make `s.transit(0,0)` excutes only after the other transitions, one way is to identify the queue and push `s.transit(0,0)` into it, correct?
And I also tried this:http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/18/, but the behavior is like a mystery to me...

Comment: Either that, but as the queue is actually filled asynchronously (after each single animation, from the callback) that would be complicated. Or you just execute `s.transit(0, 0)` in the `else` part of the `if`, i.e. when your `flag` counter has reached the limit.

Comment: I tried to execute it in else, but it just didn't work out as I would think. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/19/

Comment: You had for some reason a semicolon `;` after your `if`-statement, which caused a syntax error on your `else`. [Fixed here](http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/20/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback in your randomTran function, so it runs asynchronously. This means that randomtran() starts, and just after, s.transit({x: 0,y: 0}); is executed.

You could run s.transit({x: 0,y: 0}); in the callback of randomTran to have it execute after the rest like so :

```
var s = $('#shake');
var randomTran = function (flag,callback) {
    flag = flag || 0;
    if (flag < 6) {
        var rh = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5),
            rv = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) - 5);
        s.transit({x: rh,y: rv}, 50, randomTran.bind(this, ++flag))
    }else{
      callback();
    }
};
randomTran(0,function(){ //0 is added because randomTran expects flag as first param
  s.transit({x: 0,y: 0}); //this will be executed after randomtran calls back, eg when flag=6
});
```

but... I'm afraid you're overcomplicating things and I'm not really sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I want to achieve is like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/16/ 
After briefly shaking, the element returns to its original position.
I knew this solution but I just want to better understand concepts like 'callback','asynchronously callback' and how this 'recursive callback' works. Your codes above don't work as I anticipate, see http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/17/, after shaking, the element won't return. And I also tried this:http://jsfiddle.net/ym1aLk25/18/, but the behavior makes me totally lost my mind...