# Sequencing ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, design-patterns, queue

I find I sometimes need to iterate some collection and make an ajax call for each element. I want each call to return before moving to the next element so that I don't blast the server with requests - which often leads to other issues. And I don't want to set async to false and freeze the browser.

Usually this involves setting up some kind of iterator context that i step thru upon each success callback. I think there must be a cleaner simpler way?

Does anyone have a clever design pattern for how to neatly work thru a collection making ajax calls for each item?

Comment: Time and tide march on (as @gnarf came back and pointed out) ... as of 1.5 jQuery has a whole series of `Deferred` objects including `when()` that are great for this situation. See : http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 119, accepted):

### jQuery 1.5+

I developed an [`$.ajaxQueue()`](http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/) plugin that uses the [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue), and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) to also pass back a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) that is resolved when the request completes.

```
/*
* jQuery.ajaxQueue - A queue for ajax requests
* 
* (c) 2011 Corey Frang
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*
* Requires jQuery 1.5+
*/ 
(function($) {

// jQuery on an empty object, we are going to use this as our Queue
var ajaxQueue = $({});

$.ajaxQueue = function( ajaxOpts ) {
    var jqXHR,
        dfd = $.Deferred(),
        promise = dfd.promise();

    // queue our ajax request
    ajaxQueue.queue( doRequest );

    // add the abort method
    promise.abort = function( statusText ) {

        // proxy abort to the jqXHR if it is active
        if ( jqXHR ) {
            return jqXHR.abort( statusText );
        }

        // if there wasn't already a jqXHR we need to remove from queue
        var queue = ajaxQueue.queue(),
            index = $.inArray( doRequest, queue );

        if ( index > -1 ) {
            queue.splice( index, 1 );
        }

        // and then reject the deferred
        dfd.rejectWith( ajaxOpts.context || ajaxOpts,
            [ promise, statusText, "" ] );

        return promise;
    };

    // run the actual query
    function doRequest( next ) {
        jqXHR = $.ajax( ajaxOpts )
            .done( dfd.resolve )
            .fail( dfd.reject )
            .then( next, next );
    }

    return promise;
};

})(jQuery);
```

### jQuery 1.4

If you're using jQuery 1.4, you can utilize the animation queue on an empty object to create your own "queue" for your ajax requests for the elements.

You can even factor this into your own `$.ajax()` replacement.  This plugin `$.ajaxQueue()` uses the standard 'fx' queue for jQuery, which will auto-start the first added element if the queue isn't already running.

```
(function($) {
  // jQuery on an empty object, we are going to use this as our Queue
  var ajaxQueue = $({});

  $.ajaxQueue = function(ajaxOpts) {
    // hold the original complete function
    var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;

    // queue our ajax request
    ajaxQueue.queue(function(next) {

      // create a complete callback to fire the next event in the queue
      ajaxOpts.complete = function() {
        // fire the original complete if it was there
        if (oldComplete) oldComplete.apply(this, arguments);

        next(); // run the next query in the queue
      };

      // run the query
      $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

### Example Usage

So, we have a `<ul id="items">` which has some `<li>` that we want to copy (using ajax!) to the `<ul id="output">`

```
// get each item we want to copy
$("#items li").each(function(idx) {

    // queue up an ajax request
    $.ajaxQueue({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {html : "["+idx+"] "+$(this).html()},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            // Write to #output
            $("#output").append($("<li>", { html: data }));
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/1337/9TG8t/86/) - [1.4 version](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Fwcbj/4/)

Comment: If one send more then one request, won't the oldComplete be overwritten?

Comment: @dredrik - No, javascript handles variables in a function based scope... `oldComplete` is different for each call to `$.ajaxQueue()`

Comment: What if the ajax url depends on the return data from the previous ajax call? Any ideas how to make that work?

Comment: @galen - Check out deferred [`.pipe()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) the last example on the docs covers that scenario

Comment: This is working great for me. One question @gnarf, would I be correct in assuming that the abort method is to remove ajax requests from the queue? If so, how is it called? I tried $.ajaxQueue.abort();

Comment: @JonWilson It's on the returned promise.  Call `.abort()` on the request, the same thing you attach the `.done` too

Comment: hi excellent code thanks for posting, could you tell me how to append the response to the li from the each call rather than in a separate div, i am processing files each of my li tags has a data element and i want to add the response to the li containing the filename, hope this makes sense, maybe i should write a seperate question if its not a simple answer

Comment: ok figured it out put var $this = $(this) and then referenced $this in the success function :)

Comment: Any way to know the queue is fully empty/complete and trigger an action?

Comment: @KarlGlennon seems you can (for the 1.5+ version) use `$.ajaxQueue().done(() => console.log("all done"));`

Answer (score 14):

A quick and small solution using deferred promises. Although this uses jQuery's `$.Deferred`, any other should do.

```
var Queue = function () {
    var previous = new $.Deferred().resolve();

    return function (fn, fail) {
        return previous = previous.then(fn, fail || fn);
    };
};
```

Usage, call to create new queues:

```
var queue = Queue();

// Queue empty, will start immediately
queue(function () {
    return $.get('/first');
});

// Will begin when the first has finished
queue(function() {
    return $.get('/second');
});
```

See [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/p4zjH/1/) with a side-by-side comparison of asynchronous requests.

This works by creating a function that will automatically chain promises together. The synchronous nature comes from the fact that we are wrapping `$.get` calls in function and pushing them into a queue. The execution of these functions are deferred and will only be called when it gets to the front of the queue.

A requirement for the code is that each of the functions you give must return a promise. This returned promise is then chained onto the latest promise in the queue. When you call the `queue(...)` function it chains onto the last promise, hence the `previous = previous.then(...)`.

Comment: This works by creating a function that will automatically chain promises together. The synchronous nature comes from the fact that the $.get calls are done inside of a function and will only be called when it is its turn in the queue.

A requirement for the code is that each of the functions you give must return a promise. The returned promise is used when chaining onto the latest promise in the queue. When you call the `queue(...)` function it just chains onto the last promise, chance the `previous = previous.then(...)` Hope that helps!

Comment: I added your explanation to your answer.  Please proof and edit accordingly - not sure about "*chance the previous = previous.then(...)*" - maybe you meant "hence..."?  Anyway, thanks for the breakdown!

Comment: I did mean "hence", thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap all that complexity into a function to make a simple call that looks like this:

```
loadSequantially(['/a', '/a/b', 'a/b/c'], function() {alert('all loaded')});
```

Below is a rough sketch (working example, except the ajax call). This can be modified to use a queue-like structure instead of an array

```
  // load sequentially the given array of URLs and call 'funCallback' when all's done
  function loadSequantially(arrUrls, funCallback) {
     var idx = 0;

     // callback function that is called when individual ajax call is done
     // internally calls next ajax URL in the sequence, or if there aren't any left,
     // calls the final user specified callback function
     var individualLoadCallback = function()   {
        if(++idx >= arrUrls.length) {
           doCallback(arrUrls, funCallback);
        }else {
           loadInternal();
        }
     };

     // makes the ajax call
     var loadInternal = function() {
        if(arrUrls.length > 0)  {
           ajaxCall(arrUrls[idx], individualLoadCallback);
        }else {
           doCallback(arrUrls, funCallback);
        }
     };

     loadInternal();
  };

  // dummy function replace with actual ajax call
  function ajaxCall(url, funCallBack) {
     alert(url)
     funCallBack();
  };

  // final callback when everything's loaded
  function doCallback(arrUrls, func)   {
     try   {
        func();
     }catch(err) {
        // handle errors
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, a coroutine with multiple entry points so every callback from server can call the same coroutine will be neat. Damn, this is about to be implemented in Javascript 1.7.

Let me try using closure...

```
function BlockingAjaxCall (URL,arr,AjaxCall,OriginalCallBack)
{    
     var nextindex = function()
     {
         var i =0;
         return function()
         {
             return i++;
         }
     };

     var AjaxCallRecursive = function(){
             var currentindex = nextindex();
             AjaxCall
             (
                 URL,
                 arr[currentindex],
                 function()
                 {
                     OriginalCallBack();
                     if (currentindex < arr.length)
                     {
                         AjaxCallRecursive();
                     }
                 }
             );
     };
     AjaxCallRecursive();    
}
// suppose you always call Ajax like AjaxCall(URL,element,callback) you will do it this way
BlockingAjaxCall(URL,myArray,AjaxCall,CallBack);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, while the other answers will work, they are lots of code and messy looking. Frame.js was designed to elegantly address this situation.  https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js

For instance, this will cause most browsers to hang:

```
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    $.ajax('myserver.api', { data:i, type:'post' });
}
```

While this will not:

```
for(var i=0; i<1000; i++){
    Frame(function(callback){
        $.ajax('myserver.api', { data:i, type:'post', complete:callback });
    });
}
Frame.start();
```

Also, using Frame allows you to waterfall the response objects and deal with them all after the entire series of AJAX request have completed (if you want to):

```
var listOfAjaxObjects = [ {}, {}, ... ]; // an array of objects for $.ajax
$.each(listOfAjaxObjects, function(i, item){
    Frame(function(nextFrame){ 
        item.complete = function(response){
            // do stuff with this response or wait until end
            nextFrame(response); // ajax response objects will waterfall to the next Frame()
        $.ajax(item);
    });
});
Frame(function(callback){ // runs after all the AJAX requests have returned
    var ajaxResponses = [];
    $.each(arguments, function(i, arg){
        if(i!==0){ // the first argument is always the callback function
            ajaxResponses.push(arg);
        }
    });
    // do stuff with the responses from your AJAX requests
    // if an AJAX request returned an error, the error object will be present in place of the response object
    callback();
});
Frame.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this answer thinking that it might help other persons in future, looking for some simple solutions in the same scenario.

This is now possible also using the native promise support introduced in ES6. You can wrap the ajax call in a promise and return it to the handler of the element.

```
function ajaxPromise(elInfo) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //Do anything as desired with the elInfo passed as parameter

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/someurl/',
            data: {data: "somedata" + elInfo},
            success: function (data) {
                //Do anything as desired with the data received from the server,
                //and then resolve the promise
                resolve();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                reject(err);
            },
            async: true
        });

    });
}
```

Now call the function recursively, from where you have the collection of the elements.

```
function callAjaxSynchronous(elCollection) {
    if (elCollection.length > 0) {
        var el = elCollection.shift();
        ajaxPromise(el)
        .then(function () {
            callAjaxSynchronous(elCollection);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //Abort further ajax calls/continue with the rest
            //callAjaxSynchronous(elCollection);
        });
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/io/#queue to get that functionality.

The only solutions I can come up with is, as you say, maintaining a list of pending calls / callbacks. Or nesting the next call in the previous callback, but that feels a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing using `then`.

```
var files = [
  'example.txt',
  'example2.txt',
  'example.txt',
  'example2.txt',
  'example.txt',
  'example2.txt',
  'example2.txt',
  'example.txt'
];

nextFile().done(function(){
  console.log("done",arguments)
});

function nextFile(text){
  var file = files.shift();
  if(text)
    $('body').append(text + '<br/>');
  if(file)
    return $.get(file).then(nextFile);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/meHQHU48zLTZZHMCtIHm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a bit more sophisticated approach which is reusable for different cases.
I am using it for example when I need to slow down a call sequence when the user is typing in text editor.

But I am sure it should also work when iterating through the collection. In this case it can queue requests and can send a single AJAX call instead of 12.

```
queueing = {
    callTimeout:                 undefined,
    callTimeoutDelayTime:        1000,
    callTimeoutMaxQueueSize:     12,
    callTimeoutCurrentQueueSize: 0,

    queueCall: function (theCall) {
        clearTimeout(this.callTimeout);

        if (this.callTimeoutCurrentQueueSize >= this.callTimeoutMaxQueueSize) {
            theCall();
            this.callTimeoutCurrentQueueSize = 0;
        } else {
            var _self = this;

            this.callTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                theCall();
                _self.callTimeoutCurrentQueueSize = 0;
            }, this.callTimeoutDelayTime);
        }

        this.callTimeoutCurrentQueueSize++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple way to achieve this by adding async: false as a property to the ajax call. This will make sure the ajax call is complete before parsing the rest of the code. I have used this successfully in loops many times.

Eg.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: "GET",
    async: false
...
```