# Why does a single Ajax call work fine, but consecutive Ajax calls fail?

Tags: java, ajax, jquery, jsonp

**Setup:**

I have a Datatable, whose each row is clickable. When a row is clicked, an ajax call is made which returns some data. Sometimes the ajax call takes a little time, depending on the amount of data being returned. It is all working fine.

**Problem:**

The problem occurs when the rows are clicked quickly, one after the other. In short, before the previous ajax call returns, if the row is clicked (i.e. a new ajax call is made), I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callback' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

(The ajax call returns a JSONP data)

It looks like somehow the ajax calls are getting mingled (?), but I am not sure of this. Can anyone please tell me why does this happen?

Please let me know if any more information is required to clarify the issue.

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

Here is some ajax code:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://' + myserver + ':8080/someurl/' + my_param,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                success: function(data) {
                // Inside here, I am doing some Datatables stuff.
                var myTable = $('#my_table').dataTable( {
                        "bJQueryUI" : true,
                        "bSort" : false,
                        "bFilter" : false,
                        "bPaginate": true,
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bScrollCollapse": true,
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "aaData": samples,
                        "sEmptyTable": "No sample listings avaiable",
                        "iDisplayLength": number,
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the class which is assigning the `callback` its name. If the default callback is null, then it assigns a default value, "callback". But looks like somehow the default callback is always null and hence it always assigns "callback".

```
public class MappingJacksonJsonpConverter extends MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter {

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException,
            HttpMessageNotWritableException {

        JsonEncoding encoding = getJsonEncoding(outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = this.getObjectMapper()
                .getJsonFactory()
                .createJsonGenerator(outputMessage.getBody(), encoding);
        try {
            String jsonPadding = "callback";
            if (object instanceof JsonObject) {
                String jsonCallback = ((JsonObject) object).getJsonCallback();
                if (jsonCallback != null) {
                    jsonPadding = jsonCallback;
                }
            }
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw(jsonPadding);
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw("(");
            this.getObjectMapper().writeValue(jsonGenerator, object);
            jsonGenerator.writeRaw(")");
            jsonGenerator.flush();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And the above class is being referenced in `mvc-servlet.xml` as follows:

```
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean
            class="citygrid.feedmanager.web.converter.MappingJacksonJsonpConverter">
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                <list>
                    <value>application/x-javascript</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
```

Comment: Use synchronous ajax requests [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done)

Comment: @AlexBall: As I mentioned in the question, I am returning JSONP data (cross-domain calls) which does not support synchronous calls. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What are you using to perform your AJAX query? Could you paste your ajax code?

Comment: You can limit the number of ajax calls made at a time also post your code

Comment: Have you tried with error:, succes: and complete: ? (success callback itself)

Comment: What happens if you remove the jsonpCallback: 'callback' parameter? All the callbacks are trying to use the same callback function name, so is that where the problem is? Using a generated name may avoid this perhaps?

Comment: did u check where the error coming from? it is cause by undefined callback. perhaps it'll be assigned right after the request

Comment: `async:false` won't work with JSONP. Also it has nothing to do with server side. Chris is right: the problem is that all JSONP requests have the same callback. JQuery deletes the callback **after** JSONP returns. That's why if you fire two JSONPs quickly, the second one will try to fire `undefined` callback resulting in exception.

Comment: @Chris: If I remove the `jsonpCallback: 'callback' parameter`, I get the exact same error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callback' of object [object Window] is not a function 
`

Comment: @Down voter: care to explain?

Comment: @Bhushan That's impossible. Without the `jsonpCallback` line, jQuery doesn't even use property `callback` of `window`. Maybe stupid question, but did you clear browser cache? :)

Comment: `jsonp` required some server side work, did you do this in your server side script ?

Comment: If you are using same domain (not cross domain) then you can use `json` instead of `jsonp` and it'll make the thing easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in how jQuery works with callback with JSONP. Here's the idea:

1. JSONP is fired;
2. Callback is set;
3. JSONP returns;
4. Callback is fired;
5. Callback is deleted;

Now everything works fine if you don't define custom `jsonpCallback` (by default jQuery assigns unique callback to each JSONP request). Now what happens if you do and you fire two JSONP request at the same time?

1. JSONP1 is fired;
2. Callback with name `callback` is set.
3. JSONP2 is fired;
4. Callback `callback` is overriden by JSONP2;
5. JSONP1 returns;
6. Callback `callback` is fired for JSONP1;
7. JSONP1 deletes `callback`;
8. JSONP2 returns;
9. JSONP2 tries to fire `callback`, but that is already deleted;
10. TypeError is thrown.

Simple solution is not to override `jsonpCallback` option.

Comment: +1, That's the perfect solution IMO and jquery automatically defines a `callback` and removes it after completion.

Comment: freakish: Thanks a lot for the explanation. When you say ` not to override jsonpCallback option` what exactly do you mean? Not the define `jsonpCallback: 'callback',` in the `$.ajax`? Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: @Bhushan Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: @freakish: I tried it, but as I said earlier, I am getting same error, `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callback' of object [object Window] is not a function`. I also cleared the cache. But no luck. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: @Bhushan Are you sure that the code you've shown us is causing the problem? If so, then this is all I can do for you. Sorry and good luck!

Comment: @freakish: I just found that there is some code written by somebody else, which is assigning the `callback`. I am updating the question with details in few minutes.

Comment: @Bhushan Sorry, I'm not a Java programmer and I don't understand the details of that code. But definetly the problem *is not* on client side, but on server side. You need to debug it and figure it out. Or ask another question with `Java` tag. :)

Answer (score 4):

As Alex Ball have suggested you need to put your AJAX requests in queue, so that they are  executed one by one. It is very simple as shown [here in a post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035268/778687) (yes it works for JSON-P also).

The second thing is error message `Property 'callback' of object [object Window] is not a function` is just because you dont have a *global* function named `callback`. Just define it like :

```
window.callback= function(responseText) {
    //alert(responseText);
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1: This line: `because you dont have a global function named callback` is not true. JQuery is smart enough to automatically assign callback with name `callback`.