# How to use JSONP random callbacks with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp

I'm struggling with jQuery to handle an Ajax/JSONP request.

I'm working with two different domains, and I make several simulatenous ajax calls. Therefore, I need to rely on a callback random name automatically generated by jQuery. This code would work if I added a `jsonpCallback` setting, but simultaneous calls would be conflictual ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499672/why-does-a-single-ajax-call-work-fine-but-consecutive-ajax-calls-fail)).

Following the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), I end up with this code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.myUrl.com/myScript.php?preventCache="+new Date(),
        data: {GETvariableName:"value"},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType:'jsonp'})
    .done(function(json) {
        console.dir(json.mydata);
        })
    .fail(function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        });
```

The PHP file serves something like this :

```
callback(
    {
        "mydata":
        [
        // my JSON content...
        ]
    }
);
```

I get this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined.

Fine, which function name should I use, as it is supposed to be automatically generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php shouldn't define the `callback`, access value sent using `$_GET['callback']`

Comment: Thanks ; I juste replaced "callback" in the php file by $_GET['callback']. This makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the query parameter ?callback=function_name as the function name on the server. jQuery generates a random callback name and maps it to your .done function automatically.