# Dynamically adding Ajax requests to a queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a feature for my work and I've come to a crossroads. I'm completely new to Ajax, and am trying to implement a queue to manually handle the Ajax requests as opposed to the browser. I've done some research and looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034874/sequencing-ajax-requests), however the requests I'm going to be sending won't be declared beforehand, as the whole website is dynamic. Is there a way of using the code there in tandem with the [JQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function described here? I was thinking along the lines of:

```
$.when(d1).done(function(var d2=$.Deferred()) {
    d2.resolve();
}
d1.resolve();
```

However this implementation is not working for me. 
Thanks for any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wrapping the requests in ES6 promises, then adding them to an array, and calling [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) with the array as an argument. Via the documentation:

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when
>   all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects
>   with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

It wouldn't care where the requests were coming from, just that they either resolve or reject.

It'd look a little something like this:

```html
        let promiseArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: data => resolve(data),
                    error: err => reject(err)
                });
            });
            promiseArray.push(promise);
        }
        Promise.all(promiseArray).then((data) => {
            //Will return an array of the successful requests, or will reject on the first rejected request
            console.log(data);
        });
```

The [support for ES6 promises](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises) isn't quite universal yet, so I'd use a transpiler just in case, but it seems like Promise.all could help you.