# Jquery multiple Ajax Request in array loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can make multiple ajax requests on by one i have a big array of data and i loop through that array and in every loop i need to make ajax request to server but i want to make request only when last request is finsihed

This is my code now:

```js
// This is loop for BigData

length = BigArray.length;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  token = BigArray[i][0];
  name = titleCase(BigArray[i][1]);
  ajaxRequest(token, name);
}

function ajaxRequest(token, title) {
  $.post(APP_URL + "/message/send", {
    "_token": Laraveltoken,
    title: title,
    token: token
  }, function(data, status) {
    //When Done start next request
  });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sequencing ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034874/sequencing-ajax-requests)

Comment: I would strongly suggest you don't make AJAX requests in a loop; you can end up DDOS-ing yourself. Instead loop to congregate all data together then send that in a single request to the server.

Comment: You can use forEach https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Either set it up using promises or use a recursive loop.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you mean just a loop or multiple ajax requests in general? If to call multiple requests using recursive function, may it be the same result you mentioned?

Comment: I mean multiple AJAX requests in general. Making them in a recursive function has the same problem I mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks. Could you join the discussion by the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/61725911/3208225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve your problem with recursive function.

**Steps:**

1. Create a recursive function which will receive one parameter
2. If array length is larger than 0 continue with the function body
3. Shift array ( removes the first item from an array and store it into the variable)
4. Call our function and execute AJAX call with provided parameters, and also pass our array
5. When AJAX call is finished call our recursive function and pass our array to it

**Code:**

```
function myRecursiveFunction(myArray){
   if(myArray.length == 0) return;

   //remove first item of an array then store it into variable item
   var item = myArray.shift(); 
   //call our method which will execute AJAX call to server
   ajaxRequest(item[0], titleCase(item[1]), myArray);
}

function ajaxRequest(token, title, myArray) {
  $.post(APP_URL + "/message/send", {
    "_token": Laraveltoken,
    title: title,
    token: token
  }, function(data, status) {
    //When Done start next request
  }).always(function(){
    //call our recursive function
    myRecursiveFunction(myArray);
   });;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did the work perfectly :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

> You can use **async.js** for multiple asynchronous operation.

https://caolan.github.io/async/

**Examples:**

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) { ... },
    function(callback) { ... }
], function(err, results) {
    // optional callback
});

async.series([
    function(callback) { ... },
    function(callback) { ... }
]);
```