# Ajax calling function again when ajax is done

Tags: jquery, ajax

is there a way in ajax to wait until ajax is done, before calling the function again? Only if a button was pressed during ajax request.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $_button.on('click',function(){

       //if ajax is running, wait until done!
       init();
      });
    });

    function init(){
    //this function should be called again, when ajax is done
    }

    function ajax(){

    ..
    //ajax code
    ..

    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You call to the init() function onsuccess event in ajax call

Comment: Sounds like you want an ajax queue - there are plenty of implementations of this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequencing ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034874/sequencing-ajax-requests)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  // code which gets executed once ajax is done
});
```

By this way, once the ajax request gets completed, this will perform the requested action.

Hope this may help.

Comment: I have many ajax requests.. not only this one. If a user clicks on the button again the variables initialitation should start again, but i have to wait for ajax success, if not they will be overridden ...

Comment: in that case you can use the following to facilitate your requirement:
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $_button.attr("disabled", true);
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  $_button.removeAttr("disabled");

  // code which gets executed once ajax is done
});

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by overriding the global variables with variables inside the save function.

So on ajax success I can take the predefined variables inside the function instead of the variables outside the function.

```
function savePicture(){

      var  $_btn_edit = $btn_edit;
      var  $_btn_save = $btn_save;
      var  $_gui_resize = $gui_resize;
      var  $_img = $img;
      var  $_picture = $picture;

// here ajax request

success: function(data){
  //on ajax success
    $_picture.replaceWith($(data);
}
```

Thanks a lot!