# jQuery: Fade Out - Do Something - Fade in Pattern

Tags: jquery, user-interface, refactoring, effects

I seem to regularly write jQuery code of a pattern similar to this:

Fade Out ==> Do Something Behind the Scenes ==> Fade In
Illustrated below:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.2.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.2-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" />
var fade = "slow";

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Some event occurs
    $("#Trigger").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();        

        // Fade out target while I do something
        $("#Target").fadeOut(fade, function () {
            if (id != "") {

                // Do Something
                $("#Target").load(
                    "/Site/Controller/Action/"+id, null,
                    function () {

                        // Fade in Target
                        $("#Target").fadeIn(fade);
                    });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works fine, but the callback hierarchy gets pretty deep and **I'm just wondering if there's an easier way to do this or a better technique that doesn't result in so many levels of callbacks**

Comment: Is the Do Something step pretty instant, or does it take some time?

Comment: Hm, it could take time depending, most times it will be pretty quick but i can't garauntee that it will always be instant

Comment: Shouldn't `$("#Target").fadeIn(fade)` be called regardless of whether `id != ''`?

Comment: In this particular case no, the effect will be that if the user makes a valid selection the relevant data will be shown, otherwise the target will stay blank.  But in some other cases it may be preferible to always fade back in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2)

```
$("#Target")
    .fadeOut()
    .queue(function() {
        if (id != "")
            // Do Something
            $(this).load(
                "/Site/Controller/Action/"+id, null,
                $(this).dequeue
            );
        else
            $(this).dequeue();
    })
    .fadeIn()
```

Comment: Oh interesting, I hadn't seen that!  Nice tip!

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery.queue() you can append multiple commands to execute in sequence.
How you use it depends on what you want to do.  Here's two solutions:

1) targeting a single element:

```
$('#label')
    .fadeOut()                     //animate element
    .queue(function() {            //do something method1
        ...your code here...
        $(this).dequeue //dequeue the next item in the queue
    })
    .queue(function (next) {          //do something method2
        ...your code here...
        next(); //dequeue the next item in the queue
    })
    .delay(5000)                   //do lots more cool stuff.
    .show("slow")
    .animate({left:'+=200'},2000)
    .slideToggle(1000)
    .slideToggle("fast")
    .animate({left:'-=200'},1500)
    .hide("slow")
    .show(1200)
    .slideUp("normal", runIt)
    .fadeIn()
```

2)You could look at it another way- create a queue function which does many things, and then execute it whenever you want:

```
var $header = $("#header");
var $footer = $("#footer");

function runIt() {
    $header.queue(function(next){
        ...do something...
        next();
        }
    $header.queue(function(next){
        functionABC(variable, next);
        })
    $footer.animate({left:'+=200'},2000);
    $("#left").slideToggle(1000);
    $(".class1").slideToggle("fast");
    $(".class2").animate({left:'-=200'},1500);
    $("whatever").delay(3000);
    $(".class3").hide("slow");
      }

    runIt();    //execute it now, or...

    $(window).load(function() {  //execute it after the page loads!
       runIt();
    })
```

You can also use the queue:false variable.  This means the queue wont wait for this operation to finish, so will start the next straight away. Its useful to do two animations together:

```
function runIt() {
    $("#first").animate(
        {width: '200px'},
        {duration:2000, queue:false}
    );
    $footer.animate(
        {left:'+=200'},
        2000
    );
}
```

With AJAX, queues get a bit more complicated. Check out this post:

[AJAX Queues on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me#answer-3314877).