# jQuery Queue: Does it matter where you bind it to?

Tags: jquery, animation, queue, jquery-animate

I read this great thread: [What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me)

Now it makes me wonder:

Does it matter which DOM object you bind queue to?

i.e. `$('div').queue();` vs. `$('body').queue({})` or even `$('.foo').queue();`

Comment: @david Thanks for the fix. i'll try to do that next time

Comment: no worries, the community is built to be self-correcting in this manner. I habitually add code-markup when I see it's missing, because when it's not there, there may often be HTML code (say) in the question that is not showing because the tags are not escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element has its own queue.

Calling `$('.foo').queue();` will queue the function on *every* `.foo` element.

Comment: Which would be better practice? Or that is decided on context.

Comment: @Chris: It depends.  If you're working on a specific element, you should use its queue.  Otherwise, you should use whatever you want.