# jQuery custom queue

Tags: jquery, animation, queue, jquery-animate

What I'm trying to do is segregate animations so I can kill certain ones without effecting the important ones. I am trying to add the mouseenter/mouseleave animations to a queue so I can kill them when a different animation starts. The code below does nothing to stop the queued animations. It behaves like the default where the animations will build up in the queue and play out. What gives?

```
$('.item').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).clearQueue("test");
    $(this).queue("test",function(next){        
        $(this).animate({
            height: '250px'
        },500);
    });
    $(this).dequeue("test");
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).clearQueue("test");
    $(this).queue("test",function(next){        
        $(this).animate({
            height: '140px'
        }, 250);
    });
    $(this).dequeue("test");
})
```

Comment: Some general queue uses, explaining how custom queues operate, etc: [Can somebody explain jQuery queue to me?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1058158/91914)

Comment: Actually saw that before posting. All the examples have custom functions and not animations! Oh well. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the functions you're running in the `"test"` queue complete *immediately*, so the result is that you're *instantly* adding things onto the `fx` (default animation) queue, your `"test"` queue remains empty the entire time.

It's only has an item in it just before calling [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)...then the `fx` queue has a new entry, that queue keeps building and *that* queue you're never clearing.  It goes like this:

- `$(this).clearQueue("test");` - this queue was already empty
- `$(this).queue("test", ...);` - add item to the `test` queue
- `$(this).animate({... });` - queue up animation on the `fx` queue
- `$(this).dequeue("test");` - start the `test` queue, which is immediately emptied since `.animate()` returns instantly.

Comment: Any idea how to segregate animations using the fx queue? I can't seem to find a way to get the animation function to use a different queue...

Comment: @methodin - There isn't really `"fx"` is hard-coded as the default queue, what's the reasoning behind not using the default queue for the element?

Comment: I was typing out a response and had a eureka. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: WTF?  I came to here from the future and all you got for me is "eureka"?  Weak.

Comment: and from next future it's the same :D