# How to process one item and then go to another item in jQuery .each()

Tags: php, jquery

I have an array of checked items as code below:

```
$('input[name="numb_item"]:checked').each(function() {
var numb=this.value;
 $.ajax({
      dataType : 'json',
      data: {'numb_item': numb},
      type: 'POST',
      url:'ajxReportGenerator.php',
      success: function(data){
         $('#main_container').append(data);
      },
 });
});
```

My problem is that I wana pass first item and receive it's report then pass the secound one to the `ajxReportGenerator.php` but it will pass them once as separated parameters and it makes timeout error because in `ajxReportGenerator.php` my process will take long time and it's important to me to pass first item and receive it's report and then go to secound item...

Comment: you can't. .each executes synchronously.

Comment: [`async: false`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax) should do it, but I can't really recommend that. Instead, you should reconsider how you process the `data` you get in the `success` callback.

Comment: Is it just that you want the results to be appended in a certain order?

Comment: [look this answer.think this help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4785886/1599937)

Comment: Why you don't recommend async: false ? My function in php file is connecting to a low-speed webservice and it will give me timeout and the only think is that I have to proccess them one by one  @Blazemonger

Comment: [This question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/901048) covers that issue pretty thoroughly. Frankly, you should be trying to speed up that slow web service instead.

Comment: You're right but the webservice is not mine and I have to get a long with it :(. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

how about this loop like a tree:

```
<script>
var values = [];
$('input[name="numb_item"]:checked').each(function() {
    values.push(this.value);
});



loop = function(value,count,total,values){
    var numb = value;
     $.ajax({
          dataType : 'json',
          data: {'numb_item': numb},
          type: 'POST',
          url:'ajxReportGenerator.php',
          success: function(data){
             $('#main_container').append(data);
             count = count++;
             if(count < total){
                loop(values[count],count,total,values);
             }

          },
     });
}

count = 0;
total= values.length;
loop(values[count],count,total,values);

</script>
```

Comment: maybe you must change the memory_limit in php file content