# Ajax Request Wait Until First AJAX Call not complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below code for auto saving but i have problem lot of Ajax request firing on same time, i want to wait Ajax request Until first Ajax request not complete

```
window.submitting = false;
$('form#AddForm').submit(function() {
    window.submitting = true;
});

var timeoutId;
$('form input, form textarea, form select').bind('input propertychange change', function() {
    console.log('Change');

    if (window.submitting)
        return false;

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 5 second (5000 ms)   
        autoSave();
    }, 5000);
});

function autoSave() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form#AddForm').serialize() + '&autosave=true',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Let them know we are saving
            console.log('Saving........');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var jqObj = jQuery(data); // Ajax call here.
            var ProductId = jqObj.find("#ProductId").val();
            var url = $(location).attr('href');
            var split = url.split("add");
            if (ProductId) {
                history.pushState({}, null, split[0] + "add/" + ProductId);
                $('#ProductId').val(ProductId);
                $('form#AddForm').attr('action', '/dataproducts/add/' + ProductId);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: ajax are async. Do you need to run them adherently ?

Comment: once first Ajax request complete then second Ajax request run. i need to use .finish() Jquery or .ajaxComplete() Jquery in my code?

Comment: where is the code which triggers second ajax request, i see only one in `setTimeout` call .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like i've catch your problem. If user triggers few change events on form elements new ajax request would be created, but shouldn't until previous are in process.

My guess you can use next approach: **unbind listeners** from form elements before you send ajax and **bind them back** when ajax would be completed.

There are an excellent answer on SO regarding binding/unbinding: [Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)

So basically you have to make a litle refactoring and add few lines of code:

```
window.submitting = false;
$('form#ProductAddForm').submit(function() {
    window.submitting = true;
});

var timeoutId;
var saveHandler = function() {
    console.log('Change');

    if (window.submitting)
        return false;

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 5 second (5000 ms)
        autoSave();
    }, 5000);
};

$('form input, form textarea, form select').bind('input propertychange change', saveHandler);

function autoSave() {
    // unbind events
    $('form input, form textarea, form select').unbind('input propertychange change')
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form#ProductAddForm').serialize() + '&autosave=true',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Let them know we are saving
            console.log('Saving........');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var jqObj = jQuery(data); // Ajax call here.
            var ProductId = jqObj.find("#ProductId").val();
            var url = $(location).attr('href');
            var split = url.split("add");
            if (ProductId) {
                history.pushState({}, null, split[0] + "add/" + ProductId);
                $('#ProductId').val(ProductId);
                $('form#ProductAddForm').attr('action', '/account/products/add/' + ProductId);
            }
            // bind events back
            $('form input, form textarea, form select').bind('input propertychange change', saveHandler);
        },
        error: function{
            // bind events back even if reqeust fail
            $('form input, form textarea, form select').bind('input propertychange change', saveHandler);
        }
    });
}
```

**Note** `jqXHR.success` and `jqXHR.error` is deprecated, see [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more info. Also i've added `error` method, because you cannot miss binding listeners if ajax fails ...

Comment: After replaced jqXHR.success to jqXHR.done not working, data not reaching in this method .done()

Comment: @vikas strange, thanks for comment, i've  updated answer, just point to that moment ( deprecation of `success`, `erorr`) and added link.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood the question, but I read the question like this:

> I don't want more than one ajax requests to run at the same time. But
>   when the request is finished I want to run the next one.

You can use an ajaxManager, like suggested by [jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386886/jandy) here: [Queue ajax requests using jQuery.queue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785724/queue-ajax-requests-using-jquery-queue)

```
var ajaxManager = (function() {
     var requests = [];

     return {
        addReq:  function(opt) {
            requests.push(opt);
        },
        removeReq:  function(opt) {
            if( $.inArray(opt, requests) > -1 )
                requests.splice($.inArray(opt, requests), 1);
        },
        run: function() {
            var self = this,
                oriSuc;

            if( requests.length ) {
                oriSuc = requests[0].complete;

                requests[0].complete = function() {
                     if( typeof(oriSuc) === 'function' ) oriSuc();
                     requests.shift();
                     self.run.apply(self, []);
                };   

                $.ajax(requests[0]);
            } else {
              self.tid = setTimeout(function() {
                 self.run.apply(self, []);
              }, 1000);
            }
        },
        stop:  function() {
            requests = [];
            clearTimeout(this.tid);
        }
     };
}());
```

And to use it in your code:

```
ajaxManager.run(); 

function autoSave() {
    ajaxManager.addReq({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form#ProductAddForm').serialize() + '&autosave=true',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Let them know we are saving
            console.log('Saving........');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var jqObj = jQuery(data); // Ajax call here.
            var ProductId = jqObj.find("#ProductId").val();
            var url = $(location).attr('href');
            var split = url.split("add");
            if (ProductId) {
                history.pushState({}, null, split[0] + "add/" + ProductId);
                $('#ProductId').val(ProductId);
                $('form#ProductAddForm').attr('action', '/account/products/add/' + ProductId);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

This way you can queue different requests. However, by the code it seems that you always send the entire form. So why should the first request finish, if the next request will post a more accurate value? There can obviously be reason why you may want to post every change. But if not, you could cancel the previous request and send another one instead.

```
var xhr;

function autoSave() {
    if(xhr){
       //TODO: Check if there is a current call.
       // abort call.
       xhr.abort();
    }
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form#ProductAddForm').serialize() + '&autosave=true',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // Let them know we are saving
            console.log('Saving........');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var jqObj = jQuery(data); // Ajax call here.
            var ProductId = jqObj.find("#ProductId").val();
            var url = $(location).attr('href');
            var split = url.split("add");
            if (ProductId) {
                history.pushState({}, null, split[0] + "add/" + ProductId);
                $('#ProductId').val(ProductId);
                $('form#ProductAddForm').attr('action', '/account/products/add/' + ProductId);
            }
        },
    });
}
```