# How to send data from a controller to a view (twig) on each iteration of a loop in symfony

Tags: arrays, json, symfony, foreach, twig

I want to send a value from a controller to a view on each iteration of a foreach loop.

**Context:**

I have an array that has 100 elements as an example. In the controller, I want to loop the array and for each iteration send a value to the view. How can I do that in Symfony

Here is the code example

```
$myArray = ["val1", "val2", "val100"];
foreach ($myArray as $key => $val) {
   // here I want to send the data (val1 to val100) to the view on each iteration
}
```

**Note:**

With ***return this->json(...) or new JsonResponse(...)***, in the loop, the loop stops after the first iteration. If you put it outside of the loop, only the last val (val100 in this example) is rendered.

**Why do I want to do that?**

Let's say I am working on a symfony project to insert data into a database from excel file or something similar. After reading the file in the controller, I'm inserting the data one by one into the related table via a foreach loop and I aslo want to feed a progress bar which is in the view to let the user know that data is inserting like (1/100, 2/100 ... 100/100). How can I pass the data on each iteration from the loop to reach the view.

**Data is inserted into the db successfully**, *but I still can't find a way to feed the progress bar in the view on each iteration of the loop*

In advance, many thanks.

Comment: Instead of trying to do this inside the controller all at once, it will be more simple to separate the actions in a queue and process the queue with ajax calls

Comment: @DarkBee That way, will the progress bar be fed after the insertion into the db or while data is being inserted into the db table?

Comment: This will be during, create  a queue and execute each task one by one. This way you'll have full controll over the progress - [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554076/run-ajax-request-one-by-one-on-whole-table)

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks, I will try to understand that code...