# jQuery .when() .then() promise not adhering inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, .when

I am looping through a basic JSON Object with a `for` loop.  The JSON looks like:

```
{
  "1": {
    "project_name": "Example Project Name 1",
    "client_name": "John Doe"
  },
  "2": {
    "project_name": "Example Project Name  2",
    "client_name": "John Doe"
  },
  /// -------
}
```

The issue I am having is when looping through it. I am attempting to loop through using `.when()` and `.then()`  --  The `ajax()` calls go synchronously as expected, but the **input** for said `ajax()` is always the last index of the `JSON`.

```
function bulkUploadGo() {
    var def = $.when();

    for (var i = 1; i < Object.keys(projects_json).length + 1; i++) {
        var project = Object(projects_json)[i];

        // THIS WILL LOOP INSTANTLY -- SO I WILL SEE 1 - X INSTANTLY
        console.log(project); 

        def = def.then(function () {

             // THIS DISPLAYS SYNCHRONOUSLY, BUT IS ALWAYS SET TO THE LAST INDEX BECAUSE OF INSTANT LOOP ABOVE
            console.log(project); 

            return prepareLayer(project);
        });
    }
}

function prepareLayer(project) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/app/ajax/calls/process_project.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {project: project}
    }).then(function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data); 
        // Do stuff
    });
}
```

Obviously I am wrong in thinking that because the `def = def.then(function () {` is directly inside the `for` loop that it would "hold it" until the `return` is satisfied.  I just don't understand *why* I am wrong, and what the solution is!   How do I correctly pass `project` into `prepareLayer(project)` synchronously with the rest of the script?  I know my logic is flawed, I just can't see the forest through the trees.

For reference in explaining the outcome, here is what the `console.log()` looks like -- Where the area in blue is what happens instantly, and the rest happens with the `def.then(function () {`

[image: CONSOLE LOG]

Comment: Forgive the silly question maybe, but why would you not use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: you can use [$.ajaxQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4785886/4017803)

Comment: @Mike Not silly at all .. I have a progress bar that I am creating and running with this as well .. When I looked into `Promise_all()` it didn't look practical (possible) so I went with this approach.  I basically take 100, divide by the number of indexes and every iteration increase the width of my progress bar. Is that possible with `Promise_all()` in the way it's described on Moz ?

Comment: use async-await.

Comment: Sure, `Promise.all` simply takes an array of promises and does not itself resolve until all of those promises are done. So you are free to have each of those promises call an update to your progress bar on resolve or reject: `new Promise((resolve,reject) => { doblah().then(e => { updateProgressBar(true); resolve(); }).catch(e => { updateProgressBar(false); reject(); })` So every time a promise resolves, you can increment your progress bar, and then your "do this at 100%" goes in `Promise.all([...]).then( your code here )`

Comment: @Mike -- Perfect explanation!  Please write a quick answer. and I'll be sure to accept and upvote.  Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I've posted an answer for you (and removed all jquery because modern JS kind of no longer needs it at all)

Comment: Do you want the requests to be sent in rapid succession, and then handled as and when they return, and then continue, or do you want to send one, wait for it to complete, and then send the next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to work with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead, while tracking progress on individual tasks. Also note that modern browsers don't need jQuery here in the slightest, everything you're doing already has plain JS APIs:

```js
const APIEndpoint = `/app/ajax/calls/process_project.php`;
const yourData = { ...... };
const dataKeys = Object.keys(yourData);
const progressBar = new IncrementalProgressBar(dataKeys.length);

/**
 * You're constantly posting to the same thing: let's make that a function.
 */
function postData(data = {}) {
  return fetch(APIEndpoint, {
    method: `POST`,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": `application/json`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
}

/**
 * Turn {yourData,key} into a promise around posting your data.
 */
function keyToPromise(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = yourData[key];

    postData(data)
      .then(result => {
        progressBar.increment();
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        progressBar.increment({error: `${key} failed`});
        reject(error);
      });
  };
}

// And now we just... run through all the things
Promise
  .all(dataKeys.map(keyToPromise)))
  .then(result => moveOnWhenDone())
  .catch(error => handleException());
```

Comment: I was unaware that Promise.all had so much flexibility.. thank you for the clarification!

Comment: We could also rewrite this using `async` and `await`, since those are "syntactic sugar" around promises.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways to do this, with varying levels of parallelization.

To upload one-by-one and process one-by-one:

```js
const bulkUpload = async(arr,processResponse=identity)=>{
    for (let el in arr) {
        const response = await upload(el)
        await processResponse(response)
    }
}
bulkUpload(projects.values, processResponse).then(...)
```

To upload in parallel and process one-by one once we have all the responses:

```js
const bulkUpload = async(arr)=>await Promise.allSettled(arr.map(upload))
bulkUpload(projects.values).then((allResponses) => /* process the responses */)
```

To upload in parallel and process each response as it comes in:

```js
const uploadAndProcess = (el) => upload(el).then(processResponse)
const bulkUpload = async(arr)=>await Promise.allSettled(arr.map(uploadAndProcess))
bulkUpload(projects.values)
```

Boilerplate:

```js
const projects = { "1": { "project_name": "P1", "client_name": "C1" }, "2": { "project_name": "P2", "client_name": "C2" }, }
const identity = (x)=>x
cont URL = '/app/ajax/calls/process_project.php'
const upload = (item)=>fetch(URL, requestOptions(item))
const requestOptions = (project)=>({ method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify({ project }) })
```