# How can I know that no one AJAX request is being executed right now?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I know that no one AJAX request is being executed right now or all AJAX requests are completed?
I need to write an `if` statement. I need js native or jquery.
Like:

````
if(```no ajax pending```){
   //do some
}
````

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `fetch` or `axios` library, those returns promise. You can check `Promise.allSettled(array of promises)`.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I don't use that :(

Comment: You need to create and monitor a sort of ajax queue ... this thread may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785724/queue-ajax-requests-using-jquery-queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up events that track ajax requests in jquery

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop

```
let ajaxRunning = false ;

$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
     ajaxRunning = true;
}).ajaxStop(function() {
     ajaxRunning = false;
});

if (!ajaxRunning) {
   // nothin doin
}
```

`ajaxStop` gets tripped when all requests have been completed

Answer (score 3):

Make a wrapper around `fetch` or `$.ajax` or whichever you use that adds each request made to a Set, and check the set's size.

```
const requests = new Set();
const makeReq = (...args) => {
    const initialRequest = fetch(...args);
    const bodyRequest = request
        .then(res => res.text())
        .finally(() => {
            requests.delete(bodyRequest);
        });
    requests.add(bodyRequest);
    return initialRequest;
};
```

Then, when making a request, always use `makeReq` instead of `fetch`. No jQuery required.