# How do I kill a function when i start another one?

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I have the following code so when I click on another function I would like to stop the one is running.

So I am clicking on phone_icon and start phoneAnimation() then if I click on alarm_icon I want to stop phoneAnimating() function and start alarmAnimating()

Any idea how do I solve this as now is running the other one in behind?

```
$('#phone_icon').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    clearInterval(alarmIsAnimating);
    clearInterval(notificationIsAnimating);
    clearInterval(fbIsAnimating);
    var animation = document.getElementById('phone_sprite');
    var repeat = 0;
    var phonetl = new TimelineMax();
        phonetl.to("#phone_L", 0.5, {x:-403, ease:Power4.easeInOut})
        .to("#f2_copy", 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        .to("#initial_sprite", .8, {repeat:0, backgroundPosition:"0px -5760px", ease:SteppedEase.config(8)})           
        .to("#phone_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/active_icon1.png)"}})     
        .to("#alarm_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/alarm_icon.png)"}}, "-=0.5")     
        .to("#text_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/text_icon.png)"}}, "-=0.5")     
        .to("#fb_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/fb_icon.png)"}}, "-=0.5")     
        .to("#f2_copy1", 1, {opacity:1, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        .to(["#f2_copy3", "#f2_copy2", "#f2_copy4"], 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        .to("#initial_sprite", 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        .to("#phone_sprite", 1, {opacity:1, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1");
        phoneAnimating();
        function phoneAnimating() {
            clearInterval(phoneIsAnimating);
            // console.log('phone');
            var frameHeight = 720; 
            var frames = 9; 
            var frame = 0; 
            phoneIsAnimating = setInterval(function () { 
            var frameOffset = (++frame % frames) * -frameHeight; 
            animation.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px"; 
                if(frame == 9){
                    clearInterval(phoneIsAnimating);
                        repeat++
                        TweenLite.delayedCall(1,phoneAnimating);
                    }
                }, 100);
        } 
    });
    $('#alarm_icon').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    clearInterval(phoneIsAnimating);
    clearInterval(notificationIsAnimating);
    clearInterval(fbIsAnimating);
    var animation = document.getElementById('alarm_sprite');
    var repeat = 0;
    var alarmIsAnimating;
    var alarmtl = new TimelineMax();
        alarmtl.to("#phone_L", 0.5, {x:-403, ease:Power4.easeInOut})
        .to("#f2_copy", 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")           
        .to("#initial_sprite", .8, {repeat:0, backgroundPosition:"0px -5760px", ease:SteppedEase.config(8)})
        .to("#alarm_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/active_icon2.png)"}})
        .to("#phone_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/phone_icon.png)"}}, "-=0.5")
        .to("#text_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/text_icon.png)"}}, "-=0.5")
        .to("#fb_icon", 0.5, {css:{background: "url(images/fb_icon.png)"}}, "-=0.5")
        .to("#f2_copy2", 1, {opacity:1, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        .to(["#f2_copy3", "#f2_copy4", "#f2_copy1"], 1, {opacity:0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        .to("#phone_sprite", 0, {opacity:0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        .to("#alarm_sprite", 0, {opacity:1, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, "-=1")
        alarmAnimating();
        function alarmAnimating() {
            clearInterval(phoneIsAnimating);
            // console.log('alarm');
            var frameHeight = 720; 
            var frames = 9; 
            var frame = 0; 
            alarmIsAnimating = setInterval(function () { 
            var frameOffset = (++frame % frames) * -frameHeight; 
            animation.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px"; 
                if(frame == 9){
                    clearInterval(alarmIsAnimating);
                        repeat++
                        TweenLite.delayedCall(1,alarmAnimating);
                    }
                }, 100);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a function from running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851027/how-to-stop-a-function-from-running)

Answer (score 0):

You can use stop function to stop the currently running animation
[Here is the Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_stop.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```js
input = document.getElementById("input");
function start() {
    add = setInterval("input.value++",1000);
}start();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearInterval(add)" value="stop"/>
```

or If you are using animation then
[`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is a method for stopping animations that is running asynchronously (in the background) on the current element. It doesn't interrupt/stop any other code that isn't using the effects library.

Instead you should take a look at [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/) which lets you setup custom queues that you can clear or dequeue.

There already exist very good answers on how to use `.queue` so I'll point you to that question instead: [Can somebody explain jQuery queue to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me) - Look at the answer by gnarf.

Comment: yeah but from what I could see they use animate()