# How do I use .queue() to properly chain custom callback functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, queue

I'm trying to figure out how to chain custom functions:

I have something like this:

```
show_loader(0, function() {
    open_box($target_open, event.value, '.wide-col', function() {
        hide_loader(function() {
            scroll_to_content($target_open, function() {
            });
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Those functions have a callback implemented that looks something like this:

```
function show_loader(position, callback) {
    $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
    status = "loading"; //some non-jQuery stuff
    if (callback) $ajaxSpinner.queue( function() {callback()} );
}
```

You can see the basic idea of what i'm trying to do: execute my functions after the animations inside the functions are complete.

I don't think my code is quite right. The order should be: show loader, open box, hide loader, then finally scroll to content. Instead, it seems like this is what's actually happening when i test it: show loader, hide loader, scroll to content, then open box.

How do I get that order of function calls properly queued? And am I using the keyowrd "this" in the proper context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can see the basic idea of what i'm trying to do: execute my functions after the animations inside the functions are complete.

If you use standard animation functions from jQuery, you should be able to directly pass a callback to them. E.g.:

```
function show_loader(position, callback) {
    $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn(callback);
    status = "loading"; //some non-jQuery stuff
}
```

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com and see how they work.

**Update:**

[Here is an example that produces the desired result using `queue`](http://jsfiddle.net/WGfsS/). I'm using a newer form, where the next function to execute is passed as argument to the callback. <del>Maybe you are doing something wrong with `dequeue`</del>. *Edit: I tried your code and it works fine. I guess your are not using `queue` properly in the other functions.*

Comment: thank you thank you thank you!
I spent hours reading about .queue() including here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me/3314877#3314877 But nothing provided the exact solution i needed until your answer.

Is there a way to determine if an action is completed on some object? That'd be useful for calling next() on the event of an action being completed.

Comment: @trusktr: I guess you mean your other question? ;)

Comment: @trusktr: I wouldn't do that. I assume the order of executing the functions should is fixed, so why split it up? Create a function that calls the methods in the right order.