# How to open popup in a loop and execute callback accordingly to return status? (Greasemonkey script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I couldn't formulate proper title for this questions so I'll describe the idea/problem here.

So, currently I have 2 scripts for a task:

First script: Loops all images on specific website and if they was not voted on before we open voting popup provided by portal (max 20 images at time).

Second script: Sets vote for image and submits form, after form submits closes popup.

The problem here is that after some time popup window sets captcha field to prevent this kind of stuff :). 
So the real question is: Can I combine two scripts into one and in my loop wait for popup to open and check if captcha field is there? I could then stop loop and tell user to manually enter captcha and reload page after that. Currently (ofc) script will just run and open popups (how can i wait in loop for popup to open and load DOM) ?

Bah, really hard to explain, please tell me if need any more info.

EDIT: Ok let's change it up: **How to open popup in loop and wait for callback from popup script and only then depending on return status proceed?**

All GM script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Open image popups and vote
// @namespace      Popuopener
// @description    Open image popups and vote
// @include        http://example.com/friend/*
// @include        http://example.com/window/friend/*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

// Loop options
var start_Script = true;
var loop = 0;

// Photo rating options
var formProcessedAlready = false;

if(start_Script){

    $('form[name="form_gallery"] .img img').each(function(i,e){
        if($(this).closest('.object').children('.phs_voted_count').length == 0){
            var string = e.src;
            var nowBrake = string.substring(string.length-7,7);
            var splited = nowBrake.split('/');
            var urlStr = '/window/friend/gallery_view/'+splited[3]+'/'+splited[4]+'.html';
            wondows = window_open(urlStr, 700, 630);
            if(wondows.getElementById("vte_mark_5")){ // Trows me with wondows.getElementById is not a function
                alert("Popup loaded"); // Does not getting so far 
            }else if(wondows.getElementsByName("captcha")[0]){
                alert("Captcha inside");
                return false;
            }
            if($('input[name="captcha"]').length > 0){
                alert('Enter captcha then (F5)!');
                return false;
            }else{
                    if($('#vte_mark_5').length > 0){
                        $('#vte_mark_5').attr('checked', true);
                        $('form[name="popup_form"]').submit();  
                    }else{
                        formProcessedAlready = true;
                    }

                    if(formProcessedAlready){
                        window.close();
                    }
            }
        }else{
            loop++;
        }
        alert("End");
    }

}

function window_open(url, width, height, name, scroll_bar, location){

    _top = Math.ceil((screen.height - height)/2);
    _left = Math.ceil((screen.width - width)/2);

    if(scroll_bar != true){
        var scroll = 'no';
    }else{
        var scroll = 'yes';
    }
    if(typeof location != "undefined" && location == true){
        var location = 'yes';
    }else{
        var location = 'no';
    }

    if(name == undefined){
        name = Math.round(999999 * Math.random());
    }
    return window.open(url, name , 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',location='+ location +',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=' + scroll + ',top=' + _top + ',left=' + _left);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup windows load and close asynchronously, so things like "`wondows.getElementById("vte_mark_5")`" will not work right away.  You need wait for the popup's load event.

In Greasemonkey, you would use something like: `PopupWin.addEventListener("load",...)` (Which is best practice anyway, versus `onload=...`.)

Likewise, an ordinary loop would just open all of the popups at once.  To open the popups sequentially, use a queue.  Since you are already using jQuery, switch to version 1.5.1 to use [jQuery's queue functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058158/331508).
Note that Greasemonkey works with jQuery 1.5.1 as of GM version 0.9.

~~~
Suppose you had an array of popup URL's...

```
var URL_Array   = [ "http://jsbin.com/omuvu5/#111",
                    "http://jsbin.com/omuvu5/#222",
                    "http://jsbin.com/omuvu5/#333"
                ];
```

Then you could establish a queue with:

```
var PopupQueue  = $({});    //-- jQuery on an empty object - a perfect queue holder

//--- Load up the queue.
$.each (URL_Array, function (PopupNum, PopupURL) {

    PopupQueue.queue ('Popups', function (NextQ_Item) {
        OpenPopupFromQueue (NextQ_Item, PopupNum+1, PopupURL);
    } );
} );
```

`OpenPopupFromQueue` opens a popup and sets up the open and close event handlers...

```
function OpenPopupFromQueue (NextQ_Item, PopupNum, PopupURL)
{
    var PopupWin    = window.open (PopupURL, "_blank");

    /*--- Only after the popup has loaded can we do any processing.
        See PopupMain() for examples of manipulation via jQuery.
    */
    PopupWin.addEventListener (
        "load",
        function () {
            /*--- Setup the listener for when the popup has closed.
                We fire the next popup from the queue, there.
            */
            PopupWin.addEventListener (
                "unload",
                function () {
                    PopupClosed (NextQ_Item);
                },
                false
            );

            //--- Now process the popup, as desired.
            PopupMain (PopupWin, PopupNum);
        },
        false
    );
}
```

The load-event handler shows how you can manipulate the popup window using the main page's (GM's) jQuery...

```
function PopupMain (PopupWin, PopupNum)
{
    //--- This manipulates the main window.
    $("#PopupStatus").append ("<li>Popup Loaded.</li>");

    //--- This manipulates the popup window.
    $("#PayloadTarget", PopupWin.document).prepend ('<h3>This is popup number: ' + PopupNum + '.</h3>');
}
```

The close-event handler must trigger the next item in the queue...

```
function PopupClosed (NextQ_Item)
{
    NextQ_Item ();
}
```

Finally, you fire the queue off with:

```
PopupQueue.dequeue ('Popups');
```

**You can see [a demo that puts it all together at jsBin.com](http://jsbin.com/udaji5/4).**

Comment: wow man that's some massive post. really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: for some reason when i use 1.5.1 version of jquery it won't do the .submit(); or .trigger('submit'); while jquery 1.3.2 works fine. Any intel on why it could happen? I recreated fresh GM script to prevent any catching or w/e.

Comment: No clue about why `submit()` would break... Although, according to [the history](http://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-handlereventObject), that function was enhanced in version 1.4.3.  So, you might try using version 1.4.2, which was stable.    Otherwise, open a new question and paste or link the full script. We'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is tantamount to spam o.O But ehh, been there.

```
wnd=window_open('etc');
if(wnd.getElementById('recaptcha_response_field')){
}else{
};
```

Assuming recaptcha is your problem and that's how you open the popup window :-?

Comment: I use window.open to open popup

Comment: well, you can can save the window reference in a var, and then use that var to test for the captcha... Find something unique to the captcha (like the input name) and test for that :-? I'm uncertain what it is you want...

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i want to archive, but i have tried everything and it looks like Gresemonkey not waiting for that popup to open since no code gets executed from part where it should vote. I get .getElementById is not a function all the time.

Comment: hmz, have you tried wrapping your code into a function and doing wind.onload=yourFunction ?

Comment: Yeah, it's poorly documented but i got on the web that on* events not working in GM. Hmm thats really not fun :) I'll post whole code piece so people can examine and point stuff.