# JavaScript: Sending request and not getting response

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I am very new in JavaScript world.

```
function ButtonClickAction2 (zEvent) {              
    self.location="xxx.asp?action=go&Locale=2";
}
```

I just want to make script that when I click my "button2"(which is the buttonclickaction2 event) Firefox send a request and not get any responses.

Script must be quick. So I cant wait for the response.

---

And I have an another question.

when I clicked that button, I want firefox to go(without response)

```
self.location="xxx.asp?action=go&Locale=2" 

self.location="xxx.asp?action=go&Locale=3" 

self.location="xxx.asp?action=go&Locale=4"
```

But It automaticly goes to last(xxx.asp?action=go&Locale=4). How can I use them in a row. When It sent a request completely, It will start to send the second request.

---

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Javascript is not Java. tag removed.

Comment: Do you want to open all of those pages at the same time? If so, window.open should work.

Comment: first Locale=2, when it is complete Locale=3 after that Locale=4

Comment: I am just laughing when I see this question. Years passed, now I am a lot more experienced to understand how funny this question is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520186/how-to-open-popup-in-a-loop-and-execute-callback-accordingly-to-return-status-g/5528783#5528783) (and the question) shows how to open a list of web-pages, sequentially.

The original page stays open, as it has to keep track of things, while the new pages open, in order, in a new window.

~~~
Repeatedly changing the location of the original page, is *possible* -- but much more difficult.   It's not clear that you need to do that, anyway.