# How to search href and open part of url

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

Given this example HTML that my GM script runs on, I want to make a code that captures the ID from `http://www.mycharactersID.com/ID=234223`

After the JavaScript got 234223, and the other ID's on the page. Then open them with different link in new tabs. I mean for all ID's in the HTML.

Example: `window.open("http://www.mycharactersID.com/TalkID=234223")`.

```
Burada takılan <b>12</b> karakter bulunmaktadır.<br><br>


          <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="400">

            <tbody><tr>
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=1858480">Alexandra&nbsp;Anthony</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="DarkColumnHL">
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=2624518">Igor&nbsp;Arnaudov</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=1318025">Ashanti&nbsp;Dunn</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="DarkColumnHL">
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=621305">Abigail&nbsp;Eliopoulos</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=1853122">Fynn Linus&nbsp;Hargasser</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="DarkColumnHL">
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=2347156">Sabela&nbsp;Hernani</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=595514">Maaja&nbsp;Jürisson</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="DarkColumnHL">
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=1329193">Sixtine&nbsp;Karakaya</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=156315">Umut&nbsp;Koç</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="DarkColumnHL">
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=821852">Shanice&nbsp;Manning</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=393396">Demircan&nbsp;Özdal</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="DarkColumnHL">
              <td width="234">&nbsp;

                <a href="CharacterDetails.asp?action=view&amp;CharacterID=550724">Mélodie&nbsp;Stavropoulos</a>

              </td>
              <td align="right" width="158">

              &nbsp; </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody></table>

            <br>
            Not: En fazla 100 karakter listelenmektedir.<br><br>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is your code halfway across the question?

Comment: Do you mean e.g. `http://www.mycharactersID.com/?ID=123222`? Note the `?` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete GM script that will work.

Note that it opens all new tabs at once. To open sequentially, you'd need to queue them like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520186/how-to-open-popup-in-a-loop-and-execute-callback-accordingly-to-return-status-g/5528783#5528783).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Open lots of tabs
// @include         http://mycharactersID.com/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include         http://www.mycharactersID.com/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("td > a[href*='CharacterID']").each ( function () {
    var ID  = this.href.match (/CharacterID=(\d+)$/i);
    if (ID  &&  ID.length > 1) {
        ID  = ID[1];
        window.open ("http://www.mycharactersID.com/TalkID=" + ID,  "_blank");
    }
} );
```

Comment: Can you change your script to my new html. I couldnt edit it. İt is not working when I edit the script :(

Comment: Done.  For these kinds of questions, choosing the node selector(s) depends on precise details of the page.  So please always link to the page, if it is publicly visible.  Or, save the page's source to pastebin.com and link to that (if the page is not public or requires a registration).

Comment: You are great man! Thank you for your helps. Everytime I ask something, you helped me. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution using JQuery:

```
$('table tr td a[href^="http://www.mycharactersID.com/ID="]').each(function(){
    var regExp=/id=(\d+)/i;
    var matches=$(this).attr('href').match(regExp);
    if(matches)
    {
        window.open('url/ID='+parseInt(matches[1]), w_name, w_params);
    }
});
```

It should work.

Comment: Essentially correct, but 3 problems: (1) the selector is not specific enough. By testing all links, for such a small/common term; the odds are good that false-positive links will be found. (2) What happens if there is no match? (an exception!).  (3) Might end up with an extra "id=" in the new url.  Tweak the code and I'll upvote.

Comment: Much better.   +1 because I said I would, but there are still errors: `matches[1]` will always be undefined, and `parseInt('id=666')` is `NaN`, not 666.  Look at the regex in the other answers for clues. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure how to open links but capturing the data is easy.

```
var idArray = document.body.innerHTML.match(/"http:\/\/www\.mycharactersID\.com\/ID=([0-9]*)"/g); //captures the entire link
for(var i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++){
  idArray[i] = idArray[i].replace(/"http:\/\/www\.mycharactersID\.com\/ID=([0-9]*)"/, "$1");  //Now just the ID part
}
```

Tested and appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

this works

html

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/ID=25645" onclick="OpenMyPage(this); return false;">Click HyperLink</a>
```

javascript

```
function OpenMyPage(hyperlink) {var source = hyperlink.attributes.href.value; var pattern = new RegExp("(\\d+)$"); source.match(pattern); alert(RegExp.$1);}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FunkyFresh84/ZEAMZ/35/