# Iterating over child elements one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

as the title states, I am trying to iterate over a collection of child elements, the trouble comes in when I try to fade them out one at a time, I am using `$.each()` to try and achieve this, but it seems to be fading everything out at once, what I would like it to do is wait for the animation to finish and then go to the next child element and fade that out, here is my code,

jQuery:

```
var children = $("container").children();

children.each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div style="background: #F00;"></div>
    <div style="background: #00F;"></div>
    <div style="background: #0F0;"></div>
</div>
```

also, would it be possible to trigger an animation before the current one has finished, but delaying it by a set interval?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach:

Create an array of all the children elements, as opposed to your initial code which used a jQuery object.

```
var children = [];
$("#container").children().each(function() {
    children.push(this);
});
```

Create a function that pops one element at a time out of the array and animate it, recursively calling itself as a callback function so it will execute only AFTER the previous animation is finished.

```
function fadeThemOut(children) {
    if (children.length > 0) {
        var currentChild = children.shift();
        $(currentChild).fadeOut("slow", function() {
            fadeThemOut(children);
        });
    }
}
```

See a working demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hULDj/).

Hope this helps !

Comment: @user270311: Glad to be of help ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to fade one by one after the previous finish fading?

**[See this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hYwG/)**

```
el.fadeOut("slow", function() {
    // Fade next (see example)
});
```

**[Reference for fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)**

```
.fadeOut( [ duration ], [ callback ] )
- duration: A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
- callback: A function to call once the animation is complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an increasing `delay` for each subsequent fade:

```
var children = $("container").children();

var delayInterval = 0;
children.each(function(){
    if (delayInterval > 0) $(this).delay(delayInterval);
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    delayInterval += 300;
})
```

You will probably need to adjust the delay increment to fit to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use something like `$.queue` so you're not manually coming up with durations and timing all of your animation yourself. jQuery's [`$.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) documentation linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me) on Stack Overflow which should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Giv for your DIV's own ID's and than you can itterate over the ID's and fading one at a time out. 
For example:

var children = $("container").children().each(function()
{

for(var k=0;k< $(this).attr('id').length;k++)
{
       $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id'));
}

$(this).attr('id').fadeOut('slow');
});