# Difference between dequeue and next?

Tags: jquery, animation

In this code:

```
$('#bomb').animate({
    'top': '+=200px'
}, 3000)
    .queue(function() {
        $('#explosion').fadeIn();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });

$('#bomb').fadeOut('fast');
```

If I replace `$(this).dequeue()` with `next()`, it appears to do the same thing. What exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The passing of "`next`" to the function was added in 1.4, I think more just as a way to make code more understandable.  I think in the case you mentioned you should use `next` because it's more readable.  There are however situations when you have to use `dequeue`.

The fx queue is a special case as it will automatically `dequeue` the first element from the queue if it is empty and something is queued.  Normally this is not the case.

Consider this:

```
$("#something").queue("myqueue", function(){/*dostuff*/});
```

This alone will never execute the function passed.  A call to `dequeue` is required to start the queue moving:

```
$("#something").queue("myqueue", function(){/*dostuff*/}).dequeue("myqueue");
```

Comment: Some good info on queue here as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me