# multiple JQuery selectors in a queue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to discover if it is possible to use the .queue() method in JQuery with multiple selectors in the same queue.

I can't find any examples of where things are added to the same queue from different selectors.

for example:

```
$('#aDiv').queue(function() {
$(this).fadeOut(1000);
});

$('#someOtherDiv').queue(function() {
$(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

I want these to occur sequentially, but they appear to be happening concurrently. I have tried creating named custom queues, but that makes no difference.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to learn `queue` or would you like an attempt at a different solution for fading in/out sequentially?

Comment: Thanks Phil, I'm trying to use queue if at all possible.

Comment: I can't answer properly right now, but I think you've misinterpreted what `queue()` is used for.

Comment: Maybe I have, but from my understanding queue can be used to create a series of events to be executed in order one after the other. And that is what I need to achieve. If there is a better method to use I would be happy to use it.

Comment: I agree with Phil.  My personal feeling on this is that queue() is not the way to go so unless you're trying to learn queue() for some macabre or masochistic reason then I'd do it another way i.e. using the callback feature of fadeOut()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#aDiv').fadeOut(1000, function(){
   $('#someOtherDiv').fadeOut(1000); 
});
```

Use the callback.

Comment: He doesn't want to use `fadeOut()`

Comment: he says he just wants to "create a series of events to be executed in order one after the other" and the example he gives is using fadeOut.  This is correct given the question asked.

Comment: "I am trying to discover if it is possible to use the .queue() method "

Comment: Thanks Robert - I ended up using the callback, although I would have preferred to use the .query() because from what I understand this is more useful in complex situations where there are many actions required, and the callback method could get quite cumbersome.
However, for this situation the callback will work. So thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that queue is used to "queue" events: it's justa a way to retriev the queue of events attached to an element (look at the example in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)  ). If you want to queue events, you must do other things

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn everything that is to learn about `queue()` read this: [queue explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me)