# Getting jQuery Queue into Zepto JS

Tags: jquery, queue, zepto

I'm trying to use Zepto JS instead of jQuery for a project but Zepto JS's lack of a "queue" system like jQuery's is making things difficult for me. Has anyone made a plugin/port of jQuery's queue stuff for use with Zepto JS? Or, if not, is there a similar 3rd party alternative I could use instead?

Thanks in advance for any advice/help with this!

FYI this is a spin-off of the question from here: [using zepto, is it possible to queue animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963170/using-zepto-is-it-possible-to-queue-animations/12028841#12028841)

Answer (score 0):

i'am looking for a good solution too.

em, right now, i choose to make it by myself, just wrap a module out of zepto's animation module.

so you should code a queue by yourself, maybe it's a good time to learn who to handler animation :)

Answer (score 0):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/zohararad/6291798) worked for me. As it says, it is just a copy-paste from the JQuery source code.