# An effect with jquery animate function and absolute position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, absolute

suppose I have a div with absolute position css `{bottom:0px;}` ,then I want it collapse,I use

```
$('#id').animate({ height: "0" }, { duration: 1000 });
```

obviously it collapse from top to bottom,which means bottom fixed,top come down.

Next I want it expand with top fixed ,bottom moved,so I write:

```
$('#id2').animate({ height: "0" }, { duration: 1000 }).queue(function () {

    $('#id2').css({ top: '0' }).animate({ height: "50" }, { duration: 1000 });
});
```

but it doesn't expend,so what's wrong with my code

thank you

here is my online example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/pngK4/

Comment: I'm sure You will enjoy reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1058158/601179)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you put the animation in a queue you need to use `dequeue`.

```
$('#id2').dequeue().css({ top: '0' }).animate({ height: "50" }, { duration: 1000 });
```

Fixed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/pngK4/2/) with dequeue.

But there is really no reason to use queue, this is better:

```
    function x() {
    $('#id2').css({
        top: '0'
    }).animate({
        height: "50"
    }, {
        duration: 1000
    });
}

$(function() {
    $('#id2').animate({
        height: "0"
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: x
    });    
});
```

When the animation is over, call a `callback` function that display it. No queue involved.

[JSffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/pngK4/4/) without `queue`

Comment: thank you for solving my problem.But I still don't quite understand why I need the "dequeue",how it effect the executive order?

Comment: @hh54188. Read JQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) on queue. _"Note that when adding a function with .queue(), we should ensure that .dequeue() is eventually called so that the next function in line executes."_