# jQuery - Replacing a user message - repeats itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've got a hopefully simple problem. I've got a function that I give a user message, it displays the message in a predefined div. However, if another message comes along too quickly it changes the message, but then fades out and back in again.

This is where I am right now;-

```
function readUserMessage(message) {

    if($('#userMessage').is(':visible')) {
        $('#userMessage').fadeOut(200).html("<span style=\"\">" + message + "</span>").fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
    } else {
         $('#userMessage').html("<span style=\"\">" + message + "</span>").fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
    }

}
```

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Btw. I highly suggest checking different kind of template engines for generating html in the JS code. I have been using Mustache https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.html()` is not automatically added to jQuerys `fx queue` so it won't "wait" until your animation stuff has finished. You can workaround that by manually adding a queue entry, like

```
$('#userMessage').fadeOut(200).queue(function(next) {
     $(this).html("<span style=\"\">" + message + "</span>");
     next();
}).fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
```

Reference: [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. `fadeOut` has a callback function, which gets called once fadeout is over. You can use this.

```
function readUserMessage(message) {
    if ($('#userMessage').is(':visible')) {
      $('#userMessage').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(this).html("<span style=\"\">" + message + "</span>")
               .fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
      });
    } else {
       $('#userMessage').html("<span style=\"\">" + message + "</span>")
               .fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
    }
}
```

You can check the demo @ jsFiddle.net : http://jsfiddle.net/KZYbs/

Answer (score 0):

For such a problem, theoretically the best solution is to use a queue.

Basically, in you scenario,  any times you read a user message, you perform an action. If you want to manage those actions, you can put them in a queue and then manage them.

The code jAndy posted is very interesting, and if you want to learn more on queues, they are excellently explained [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me) and [here on jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) .

Spending some time on this subject can be very helpful, as queues can come useful in a plethora of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the queue to be finished before calling an other effect (fade, slide, etc) with the [stop function](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).