# how to make a set of jquery effects run in sequence

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a set of jQuery effects that I would like to have run one after the other (currently they run simultaneously. Is there any way to fix this?

The code is as follows:

```
 <SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".right").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200);
    });

    // Trigger the handler once on document ready
    $(".right").click();

});
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#left").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200);
    });

    // Trigger the handler once on document ready
    $("#left").click();

});
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#up").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1200);
    });

    // Trigger the handler once on document ready
    $("#up").click();

});
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3314877/7613 specifically custom queue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks. Callbacks are functions that run when another function is complete, in this case your animation.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Also you do not need so many declarations. Try is like this

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

           $('.right').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200, function(){
                  //first callback
                  $('#left').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200, function(){
                          //second callback
                          $('#up').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1200);
                  });
           });

    });

</script>
```

If you want animations to also trigger on click, you can do so by using the same .click statements you have now, just no need to //Trigger the handler on document ready

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you after!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".right").click(function () {
             $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200, function() {
                  $(".right").click();
             })
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you going to sequence it.. Check below as an example and modified as you wanted it,

The final argument of the [.show](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/show) is a call back function which will be called after executing `.show`

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".right").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200, function () {
                // Trigger the handler once on document ready
                $("#left").click();
         });
    });

    $("#left").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200, function () {
              $("#up").click();
         });
    }); 

    $("#up").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1200);
    });

    // Trigger the handler once on document ready
    $(".right").click();
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the next animation the first animations callback to animate them in sequence and the callback is the last argument of the `show` method.

Also instead of using multiple `$(document).ready()` you can club all together in just one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#left").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1200, function () {
              $("#up").click();//Trigger up click
         });
    }); 

    $("#up").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1200);
    });

    $(".right").click(function () {
         $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1200, function () {
              $("#left").click();//Trigger left click
         });
    }).click();//Trigger the right click
});
```