# Fade out DIV and fade in next DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to build a slider from scratch only im a bit stuck, I basically want each div to fade out and the next one to fade in straight afterwards, once each div has faded in, i want the image within that to animate, I've made a fiddle to try and explain. Thanks for any help!

http://jsfiddle.net/FeqkB/2/

Comment: Have you checked out the queue? Maybe that will help, since you can have callbacks for when each animation finishes. http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: This is a good resource for using the queue, if you go that route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to make use of **callback** functions when you want to create **sequential** animations. If you do it the way it is done in your fiddle, you launch all the effects at the same time, resulting in a messy behavior.
The functions fadeIn, fadeOut and animate all take a callback function.
Let's say you want fadeIn, then animate, then fadeOut.

1. fadeIn is called with a callback which will animate
2. animate is called with a callback which will fadeOut

I forked your fiddle to give you an example, but I did it just for the first div. If you understand this mechanism, it will be easy to extend it for any number of effects. Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/bBxUQ/1/