# Auto-start jQuery custom queue

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-queue

[As explained in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467419/how-does-the-fx-queue-in-jquery-auto-start), `If the queue being queued is fx and the queue is not already in progress, dequeue is called.`.

That is great that the default queue is smart enough to auto start. **But how can I replicate the same functionality, auto starting when the queue is empty, for my custom queue?**

My problem is I am receiving Pusher calls (ajax calls that come to the page) that activate the code below to add a new name to `#tickerlist`. The problem is, to get the queue started, I have to add `.dequeue` outside the queue, which then forces `tickerlistqueue` to start the next item in the queue. When you've got several Pusher calls coming in at once, this effectively renders the queue useless - *the jobs just run over each other because that's exactly what I'm telling it to do.*

Essentially what I need is to only run the `.dequeue` line when the queue is empty. Otherwise, don't run that line, the queue will take care of itself.

```
var tickerlist = $('#ticker-list');

tickerlist.queue('tickerlistqueue', function(next) {
    var name = 'John';
    $(name).hide().prependTo('#ticker-list').slideDown(700, function () {
        $('#ticker-list>div:last').remove();
        next();
    })
});

tickerlist.dequeue('tickerlistqueue'); //This is the only way to start the queue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh; my last paragraph answered my own question. [jQuery shows you how to get the size of the queue in it's first example](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

If queue `length` is 1 or less, start the queue. Otherwise, don't do anything. It's 1, not 0, because you are calling this after you queue the latest name.

Particular to my example:

```
if (tickerlist.queue('tickerlistqueue').length <= 1) {
    tickerlist.dequeue('tickerlistqueue');
}
```