# How to highlight some elements in a "rotating" fashion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my problem: when the user clicks on the "validate" button, I send an AJAX request that returns an array of "problematic" elements. From that array, I compute the id of the elements I want to highlight then I "flash" them.

This is nice, it works, but they **all flash together**.

I want to flash them one after the other, so that it's longer and looks nicer (= not aggressive). I've spent some time trying to use `queue()` function (I guess it's the way to go) but didn't manage to make it work.

Any idea how to do this?

```
/* this is the function to retrieve bg color (= not the actual subject) */
jQuery.fn.getBg = function() {
    return $(this).parents().filter(function() {
        var color = $(this).css('background-color');
        return color != 'transparent' && color != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    }).eq(0).css('background-color');
};

/* this is my flash function (= not the actual subject) */
function flash(id, font_color, bg_color, nb) {
    var bc=$(id).getBg();
    var cl=$(id).css('color');
    var mx=parseInt(nb);
    if (mx<=0) {
        mx=1;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<mx; i++) {
        $(id).animate({
            backgroundColor: bg_color,
            color: font_color
        }, 200)
        .animate({
            backgroundColor: bc,
            color: cl
        });
    };
}

function localOnAjaxError(dataMessage)
{
  var msg='';
  $('#wait').hide('slow');
  /* show the form again and highlight errors */
  $('#s-inscrire-form').show('slow', function() {
    if (msg!='') {
      $('#erreur').fadeIn('slow');
      flash('#erreur', "#f9e4c9", "#aa0000", 3);
    }
    if (dataMessage instanceof Array) {
      for (key in dataMessage) {
        var m=dataMessage[key];
        if(m.indexOf('#error')==0) {
          /* show the id... */
          $(m).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            /* ...then flash the corresponding label */
            flash('#label-'+this.id.substr(7), "#ffffff", "#aa0000", 3);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
  seConnecterAssigneClicksConnexion();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working solution:

```
dataMessage = new Array("#erreur-nomprenom", "#erreur-adresse1", "#erreur-cp", "#erreur-ville", "#erreur-tel");
var theQueue = $({});
for (key in dataMessage) {
    var m = dataMessage[key];
    if (m.indexOf('#erreur') == 0) {
        var toFlash = (function(m) {
            return function(next) {
                $(m).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                    flash('#label-' + this.id.substr(7), "#ffffff", "#aa0000", 3);
                    next();
                });
            }
        })(m);
        theQueue.queue('flash', toFlash);
    }
}
theQueue.dequeue('flash');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the animation queue from your `flash` function. Then, instead of starting all flashes together in your for-loop (btw: for-in-loops are not suited for arrays), you will need to push them recursively on that queue. What have you tried with [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)?

Answer (score 0):

You would be correct to use jQuery's `queue` method.  Here's an example that takes all divs and changes their color in sequence.

```
var theQueue = $({});

$('div').each(function(index, div) {
    theQueue.queue('flash', function(next) {    
        $(div).animate({
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }, 500, function() {
            next();
        });    
    });
});

theQueue.dequeue('flash');
```

**Live example** - http://jsfiddle.net/z7xRe/

There's another question on Stack Overflow that walks through this use case in more detail here - [What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me).  See @gnarf's response.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, but, relying on your sample I've tried to make it work but it doesn't, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8yKP/1/

Comment: To do color animations you need to include jQuery UI as well (see http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).  I clicked the checkbox to bring in jQuery UI on your jsFiddle and it works as expected - http://jsfiddle.net/78zar/.

Comment: Ok, now I'm facing the last problem: when elements are in an array. http://jsfiddle.net/k8yKP/2/  => sorry, when it comes to JavaScript I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed ..

Comment: Here's my stuff with console.log() added, I don't know how to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/k8yKP/3/

Comment: I've added the working solution, thank you for putting me on the right track!