# jQuery Animation queue doesn't start

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Why does following code snippet doesn't work?
It doesn't gives any error, but also it doesn't work.
About empty object I watched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var o = jQuery({});         
        var block = jQuery('#box');
        jQuery('#start').click(function(){
            o.queue('custom',function(next){
                block.animate({left:"+=500"},1000);
                next();
            });
            o.queue('custom',function(next){
                block.animate({left:"-=500"},1000); 
                next();
            });
            o.queue('custom',function(next){
                block.animate({top:"+=500"},1000);      
                next();
            });
            o.queue('custom',function(next){
                block.animate({top:"-=500"},1000);  
                next();
            });

            o.dequeue('custom'); 
        });
    });

</script>
```

**UPDATE 1**

If I insert console.log right before and right after dequeue call like this:

```
            console.log(o.queue('custom').length);
            o.dequeue('custom'); 
            console.log(o.queue('custom').length);
```

then I get 4 0 in console. Meaning that functions are added to the queue and therefore dequeued.

**UPDATE 2**

If I insert console.log right after block animate, for instance, like this:

```
                block.animate({left:"+=500"},1000);
                console.log('1');
```

then I get 1 2 3 4, which means that all 4 functions are called.

**UPDATE 3**

My html is very simple:

1 input button and 1 div in body tag.
div has following css:

```
width:200px;height:200px;display:block;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 green
```

Comment: You are applying the queue to `o` which is a plain jQuery object. Try applying it to `block`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, unfortunatelly no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/icomon) (you can edit it with the button in the top right corner).

You need to set `position:relative` on the `#block` element. Without it, the `div` will not be affected by the property changes applied, because [the initial value of the property is `static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position)).

From the MDN docs, the `static` position means:

> Normal behavior.  The top, right, bottom, and left properties do not
>   apply.

However, the property does of course get changed for static elements, as you can see in this [example](http://jsbin.com/icomon/2) (check the console). But they do not have any visible effect.

Hope this helps. You may revert all other changes to your code I made, that was done before setting the position.

Comment: position:relative is the reason. "The top, right, bottom, and left properties do not apply" in static. Well, very interesting note. Thank you.