# Can I stop a started animation?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this animation that start at some point :

```
myElement.animate({ top: -currentTempImageX, left: -currentTempImageY }, 5000);
```

that take 5 seconds to animate! Suppose I want to stop it after 2 seconds. Can I have this control?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
myElement.stop();
```

Link: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

If you want to stop the animation after 2 seconds then use,

```
setTimeout(function(){myElement.stop();}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

User setTimeout() as suggested by Bhuvan Rikka , 
for stop that use clearTimeout() function ..
for example see this link

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

You may also check the FX queue (used for the jquery animations)

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

or this other topic.

[What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me)