# jQuery slide and fade out with delay doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am writing a notification plugin for jQuery. As part of the plugin the notifications can be set to auto disappear after a certain time.  For some reason though it only fades out and doesnt `slideUp` as I'd expect it to.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#' + plugin.uniqID)
    .delay(plugin.settings['autoclose'])
    .queue(function () {
        $(this)
            .fadeOut({ duration: plugin.settings['speed'], queue: false })
            .slideUp(plugin.settings['speed']);
        });
```

Comment: What if you swap the animation functions? Stupid suggestion but I'm not very experienced with JQuery animations, I usually just use the `animate` function with a CSS map.

Comment: Interestingly, if I re-order the same occurs.  Also if I remove the fade completely the `slideUp` never works - now im really confused!

Comment: have you tried adding a `.delay()` after the `.fadeout()` and before the `.slideup()`?

Comment: That does sound really strange... I just went through the documentation of the queue method. You **are** using a version of JQuery > 1.4 right? Otherwise you need to manually dequeue your function...

Comment: Try adding a .dequeue() after the last closing in your code. There is a lot of info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me

Comment: I don't see a queue in the [syntax](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), `.fadeOut( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )`

Comment: what value does plugin.settings['speed'] have ?

Comment: Currently "1500"... I have come up with a workaround using slideDown and fadeIn for the animation to show the popup and using `.animate({ duration: plugin.settings['autoclose'], height: 0, opacity: 0 })` to hide it, which works almost as I'd like it

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative suggestion, could you not just use animate and change the height and the opacity within the animate function? like so:

$(this).animate({
            height:"whateverheight",
            opacity:"whateveropacity"
        }, whateverspeed);

Comment: I did try that with some success (i.e. using 'toggle') but it never started or returned to a height of 0 like slide up and down does.

Answer (score 1):

adeneo was right you'll need to call [.dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)

http://jsbin.com/opiluy/1/edit

```
$('#' + plugin.uniqID)
    .delay(plugin.settings['autoclose'])
    .queue(function () {
        $(this)
            .fadeOut({ duration: plugin.settings['speed'], queue: false })
            .slideUp(plugin.settings['speed']);
        }).dequeue();
```

Comment: This works perfectly on jsBin but not in my plugin, ill look into it

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify `queue: false` for both animation calls. This will work fine.

```
$('#' + plugin.uniqID)
.delay(plugin.settings['autoclose'])
.queue(function () {
    $(this)
        .fadeOut({ duration: plugin.settings['speed'], queue: false })
        .slideUp({ duration: plugin.settings['speed'], queue: false });
    });
```

Comment: This seems to call the fadeOut / slideUp the instant the previous animation (of showing the notficiation) finishes

Comment: [This seems to work as well](http://jsbin.com/opiluy/4/edit) just like [using dequeue](http://jsbin.com/opiluy/1/edit). Strange I can't find queue option documented though.

Comment: Also you can use .stop() function to stop animation. There is an example for you http://jsfiddle.net/pXvaj/