# How to ensure the right order of created Backbone models in collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am uploading files asynchronously (using FormData) at specific index in the list of files with:

```
files.create({position: index + 1 }, {at: index}); // files is Backbone.Collection
```

The server then saves upload and shifts positions for the files after specific position to free the place for the new inserted file.

Then on client I listen to add event and use index from options to insert file view.

```
files.on("add", function(model, collection, options) {
    // insert file view at options.index position
})
```

I also update `position` attribute for all models in collection:

```
files.on("add remove", function(){ 
  this.each(function(m, index) {
    m.set({position: index + 1});
  })
});
```

The problem is when I upload many files at one time at the same index position, file views append to the list in the wrong order.

How to ensure correct order and `position` attribute for file models in backbone collection?

Comment: Can't you use a [`comparator`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) to keep the collection sorted by `position`?

Comment: When I insert new models in collection, the positions of the rest models are changed on server (client doesn't have this info)

Comment: And I also need positions to stay in sync with the server for drag n drop sort to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override collection.create that queues ajax requests. To do so I used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me/3314877#3314877).

```
var Documents = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: Document,

  url: "/a/documents",

  initialize: function() {
    this.on("add remove", this.updatePositions, this);
    this.ajaxQueue = $({});
  },

  updatePositions: function(model, collection, options) {
    this.each(function(m, index) {
      m.set({position: index + 1});
    })
  },

  create: function(model, options) {
    var jqXHR
      , dfd = $.Deferred()
      , promise = dfd.promise()
      , coll = this;

    // queue our ajax request
    this.ajaxQueue.queue(doRequest);

    // add the abort method
    promise.abort = function(statusText) {
      // Proxy abort to the jqXHR if it is active
      if (jqXHR) {
        return jqXHR.abort(statusText);
      }

      // If there wasn't already a jqXHR we need to remove from queue
      var queue = this.ajaxQueue.queue()
        , index = $.inArray(doRequest, queue);

      if (index > -1) {
        queue.splice(index, 1);
      }

      // Reject the deferred
      dfd.rejectWith(options.context || options,
                     [promise, statusText, ""]);

      return promise;
    };

    // Run the actual collection.create
    function doRequest(next) {
      options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
      model = coll._prepareModel(model, options);
      if (!model) return false;
      if (!options.wait) coll.add(model, options);
      var success = options.success;
      options.success = function(nextModel, resp, xhr) {
        if (options.wait) coll.add(nextModel, options);
        if (success) {
          success(nextModel, resp);
        } else {
          nextModel.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
        }
      };
      jqXHR = model.save(null, options)
        .done(dfd.resolve)
        .fail(dfd.reject)
        .then(next, next);
    };

    return promise;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript-originated position, use server generated id, for example unix timestamp, and as mu is too short suggested, sort your collection using

```
comparitor: function() { 
    return -this.timestamp // negative ensures latest items show up on top, and olders at the bottom 
}
```

if you need more specific sorting you can always ether go to a more granular microtime, or simply generate an incremental id server-side.

Comment: I don't need chronological order. It should work with javascript position as a sorting key. Server then updates positions to ensure they are incremental. But because each file is uploaded asyncrously, files are inserted in the wrong order. I was able to override collection.create to queue Ajax requests. It seems to work.