# Jquery ajax post request overlapped with old ones

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building rss feed reader using php and jquery on wamp server.

On page load, I have list of websites,

```
<ul class='list'>
     <li>Site1 <input type='hidden' value='http://site1.rss/' /></li>
     <li>Site2 <input type='hidden' value='http://site2.rss/' /></li>
     <li>Site3 <input type='hidden' value='http://site3.rss/' /></li>
</ul>
```

For fetching feeds from "getFeed.php" page, I use jquery code,

```
$('.list li').live('click', function() {
     var url = $(this).find('input').val();
     $.post("getFeed.php",
            {url:url},
            function(data) {
                 $('.feed').html(data);
            });
});
```

This code is working like a charm. Now the problem occur if I click on another site, before first site's request completes.

At that time if first site's response is slow, then I got result from second site as it should. But when first site response late, result changes to first site.

The question is similar to [question]: [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

I already try this code, but not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var xhr;

     $('.list li').live('click', function() {
          xhr.abort();
          alert("testing flag");
          var url = $(this).find('input').val();
          xhr = $.post("getFeed.php",
                 {url:url},
                 function(data) {
                      $('.feed').html(data);
                 });
     });
})
```

But, this code fails sending requests. So, I put one testing alert flag after xhr.abort() line. But alert also not working. May be problem in xhr.abort(); line.

Comment: What do you mean by `xhr.abort()` isn't working? from your code, the only way it's not working, is that nothing should work, because you're calling `.abort()` on an undefined variable. Other than that, `xhr.abort()` WILL work.

Comment: Are you sure you want to abort? I am not even sure it works in all browsers and if it does, the user will likely be surprised that he does not get what he clicked. I would a) use .on instead of live which is deprecated and b) block clicking while the result is fetched or better: queue the clicks

Comment: @mplungjan, I changed all .live function with .on => Great improvement in my code. Thanks for that.
Working on queue the clicks, as it's new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xhr.abort();` will cause an error since xhr is undefined the first time you call the function, Try something like `xhr && xhr.abort();`

Comment: Thanks man. I understand the problem. The code should be,
if(xhr) {xhr.abort();}

Comment: ^^ Glad that was the fix you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to abort? I am not even sure it works in all browsers and if it does, the user will likely be surprised that he does not get what he clicked. I would

a) use `.on` instead of `.live` which is deprecated and
b) block clicking while the result is fetched or better: queue the clicks

See: [What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me/3314877#3314877)

there is an ajax queue example