# use of jquery next() in this queue function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was reading about jquery `queue()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314877/1252748). The first answer is pretty comprehensive:

```
var theQueue = $({}); // jQuery on an empty object - a perfect queue holder

$.each([1,2,3],function(i, num) {
  // lets add some really simple functions to a queue:
  theQueue.queue('alerts', function(next) { 
    // show something, and if they hit "yes", run the next function.
    if (confirm('index:'+i+' = '+num+'\nRun the next function?')) {
      next();
    }
  }); 
});

// create a button to run the queue:
$("<button>", {
  text: 'Run Queue', 
  click: function() { 
    theQueue.dequeue('alerts'); 
  }
}).appendTo('body');

// create a button to show the length:
$("<button>", {
  text: 'Show Length', 
  click: function() { 
    alert(theQueue.queue('alerts').length); 
  }
}).appendTo('body');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkBJk/)

I can't understand how `next()` (line 8) is working however. I get that if I comment it out the "next" confirm box fails to pop up until I press the button again, but I thought `next()` was used primarily for traversing the dom. Here though, it seems like it's telling the function to run again.

Also, if the queuing of the `confirm` boxes is within the `each()` function, why would they all be queued successfully without the `next()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next` is a parameter in the callback function to queue.  *Do not* confuse it with `.next()`, the jQuery collection method used for DOM navigation.

You can actually make the parameter anything you want in the callback [as I demonstrate here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/mkBJk/249/).  The name `next` is not particularly significant; it just makes sense in the documentation.

This parameter is itself a function (callback) that is passed to `.queue` by jQuery's internals.