# jQuery effects/animation is delayed in execution

Tags: jquery, animation, effects

With the following code everything is displayed normally and in sequence in the Firebug console with the entries in order (including the Ajax post of the data) but all the jQuery effects/animations (`fadeIn`, `animate`, `slideUp`, `slideDown`, `animate`, `fadeOut`) happen together at one time after the call to my Ajax function not when the actual step is executed.

Why is it doing this? How do I fix it?

```
$('#overlay').fadeIn(500, function () { 
  $('#overlaybox').animate({ 'top': '40px' }, 100);
});
$('#survey').slideUp(1500);

console.log('-after overlay show');
console.log('before ajaxPutSurveyItems()');

ajaxPutSurveyItems(save, after);

console.log('after ajaxPutSurveyItems()');

$('#survey').slideDown(1500);
$('#overlaybox').animate({ 'top': '-200px' }, 300, function () {
  $('#overlay').fadeOut(2500); 
});

console.log('-after overlay hide');
```

here is ajaxPutSurveyItems

```
function ajaxPutSurveyItems(answers, nextstep) {
    console.log('ajaxPutSurveyItems()');
    var p = {};
    p.uniqueid = gUniqueID;
    p.answers = answers;
    p.pageid = gSurveyPages[gCurrentPageIndex].ID;
    p.pageindex = gCurrentPageIndex.toString();
    p.surveydefid = gSurveyID;
    p.bypass = gIsBypass;
    var j = JSON.stringify(p);
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "surveydata.asmx/putSurveyItems",
        data: j,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(XHR) {
            console.log(':beforeSend');
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log(':success');
            // code removed for brevity
        },
        error: function (XHR, errStatus, errThrown) {
            console.log(':error');
            // code removed for brevity
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire page, including HTML please?

Comment: I suggest reading up on "callback" functions.

Comment: ajax call is Sync or Async ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me

Comment: the code is very large and not appropriate to post.  basically a button click event fires this code and all looks fine in Firebug console, but the effects/animations all execute after the call to my Ajax data save routine.  This is the simplified version of the problem using beforeSend: and complete: in the Ajax call.

Comment: what does `ajaxPutSurveyItems` look like? and what are `save` and `after`?

Comment: @steo - currently it is async: false

Comment: @darshanags - save and after are strings... '107|9' and 'next' are examples

Comment: Uhm.. I am not sure, but `async : false` let the call to be synchronous and so the script wait for it. Or at least I guess so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you're not waiting until one animation has finished before you start the other. You have just set them up to in effect start all at the same time. Whilst you have used some callbacks i'm confident you understand how they work and just need to put more in.

So `callbacks` are needed:

```
 $('#overlay').fadeIn(500, function () { 
   $('#overlaybox').animate({ 'top': '40px' }, 100);
 });
 $('#survey').slideUp(1500, function(){

      console.log('-after overlay show');
      console.log('before ajaxPutSurveyItems()');

      ajaxPutSurveyItems(save, after);

      console.log('after ajaxPutSurveyItems()');

      $('#survey').slideDown(1500, function(){

            $('#overlaybox').animate({ 'top': '-200px' }, 300, function () {
              $('#overlay').fadeOut(2500); 
            });     
      });

      console.log('-after overlay hide');
 });
```

Comment: i had the show effects in the beforeSend: and the hide effects in the complete: of the actual ajax call but the same effect was happening.  basically the button click happens then it seems like the browser is hung until the end of the ajax call (which currently calls a SQL sproc delayed for 5 seconds) when all the effects fire.

Comment: thanks! this worked great!  sans the misspelled 'function' in the slideDown effect.