# Why use next() to add and remove a class multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I really want to know why it's important to use `function(next)` and `next()` in the following code. Without `next()` you can only remove the class `.open-sidebar` one time after you added it by clicking the `.header__menu__button--profile`.

I thought `next()` is used to select the following sibling of an element!

Why do I need it to remove the class `.open-sidebar`every time I click on `.sidebar__top__button--close`?

```
$('.header').on('click','.header__menu__button--profile',function(){
    $('.sidebar').addClass('open-sidebar');
});

$('.sidebar').on('click','.sidebar__top__button--close',function() {

    if($('.sidebar').hasClass('open-sidebar'))
    {
        $('.sidebar').delay(300).queue(function(next){
            $('.sidebar').removeClass('open-sidebar');
            next();
            });         
    }

});
```

Comment: Welcome to asynchronous programming. Read up on how jQuery's [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2) and asynchronous programming in general works.

Comment: next must be defined somewhere.

Comment: @HerrSerker it is - it's in the callback's parameter list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me

Answer (score 5):

In this case, `next` is the *parameter* that was passed by jQuery to the `.queue` callback, which is a reference to the *next* function in the animation queue.

It's nothing whatsoever to do with `.next()`, the function that selects the next sibling elements from a jQuery collection.

It's used within `.queue` because you have to tell jQuery to process the remaining animation queue once you've done whatever it is you need to do, i.e.:

```
.queue(function(next) {
    // do stuff
    ...
    next();
})
```

or you can use `.dequeue` instead:

```
.queue(function() {  // NB: no parameter
     // do stuff
     ...
     $(this).dequeue();
})
```

The latter is actually the older way of doing this - the `next` parameter was introduced in jQuery 1.4 and if using multiple queues avoids the need to repeat the queue name in both the `.queue` and `.dequeue` calls.