# Queue() / dequeue() JQuery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I've been working with CoffeScript and JQuery. I need to create a simple animation.

I tried using delay and I didn't understand it at all, so I read a question before:

[Link from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me)

So I decided to use queues; the main problem is that just the last element of the animation is  considereded although the queue has more elements inside.

I Hope you could help me :), You can find the codes below.

All the elements inside the queue (CoffeScript).

```
    for proc in listaDeProcesos
    id = proc.id
    nombre = proc.nombre
    idFinal = "#{id}#{nombre}"
    tiempo = parseInt(proc.tejecucion)
    $("#animacion").queue('chain',(next)->
            $("##{idFinal}").fadeOut(tiempo,->
                    next()
                )
        )
```

The dequeue function call:

```
        $("#animacion").dequeue('chain')
```

Comment: May be your indentation is somehow messed up so the loop is exhausted and the rest of the code is using only the last value of `proc` (outside of the loop).

Comment: I don't get it. I've solve it using an auxiliar queue and adding the effects individually. Thanks I'll read my code again, the indentation is a headache sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations! Butting your head against this is a rite of passage for all JavaScript (or CoffeeScript) developers. You were bound to run into it eventually. The explanation is twofold:

- JavaScript (and CoffeeScript) variables are function scoped, not block scoped
- [Closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science))

Basically, each iteration creates a function with a reference to the *variable* `idFinal`, not the *value* of `idFinal` at that iteration through the loop. So when later iterations change `idFinal`, it changes it for all the functions that you've created. See here for a simpler example of the behavior:

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

One way to get around this in CoffeeScript is to introduce a new scope with the `do` construct:

```
for {id, nombre, tejecucion} in listaDeProcesos
  do (idFinal = "#{id}#{nombre}", tiempo = parseInt(tejecucion)) ->
    $("#animacion").queue 'chain', (next) ->
      $("##{idFinal}").fadeOut tiempo, next
```

Comment: Wow it seems I have a lot of things to learn about JS and CoffeeScript, I've solved the problem using other method, thanks anyway I'll check the link your giving in order to improve myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution, in case someone else has the same problem I write the code below, Thanks anyway :)

All the code is in coffeescript.

Animated Element class

```
class animatedElement
constructor: (@element,@time) ->
showInfo: ->
    alert ("#{@element} >> #{@time}")
```

Iteration of what you want to animate:

```
for proc in listaDeProcesos
    id = proc.id
    nombre = proc.nombre
    idFinal = "#{id}#{nombre}"
    tiempo = parseInt(proc.tejecucion)
    elemento = new animatedElement($("##{idFinal}"),tiempo)
    queue.push(elemento)
```

Auxiliar function

```
showAnimation = ()->
if (queue.length > 0)
    tiempo = queue[0].time
    (queue.shift().element).fadeOut(tiempo, showAnimation)
```

And finally you just need to call

```
showAnimation()
```

I hope it could be useful for someone else :)