# Staggering CSS Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have a CSS animation that I want to be applied in 200ms intervals. I've set up the CSS like this:

```
.discrete {
    position:relative;
    opacity:1;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
    -o-transition: all .5s linear;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}

.discrete.out {
    left:-40px;
    opacity:0;    
}
```

I then want to stagger the application of the `.discrete.out` class in 200ms intervals. I've tried the following:

```
$('.discrete').each(function() {
    $(this).delay(200).addClass('out');
});
```

And this:

```
$('.discrete').each(function() {
   var theNode = $(this); 
   setTimeout(function() {
       theNode.addClass('out');
    }, 200);
});
```

But in both cases, the animation just occurs all at once!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
var els = $('.discrete'),
    i = 0,
    f = function () {
        $(els[i++]).addClass('out');
        if(i < els.length) setTimeout(f, 200);
    };
f();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/56mUn/)

Comment: Marked this one as accepted because this method seems to be significantly faster than using the jQuery animation queue! Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the jQuery animation queue: http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/7zm6q/2/

```
function createWorkQueueFunction($element) {
    return function(next) {
        $element.addClass("out");
        next();
    };
}

$('button').click(function() {
    var queue = $({}); //use the default animation queue
    $(".discrete").each(function() {
        queue.queue(createWorkQueueFunction($(this)));
        queue.delay(200);
    });
});
```

**But why don't your examples work?**

The reason why the following doesn't work is because jQuery will immediately add the 'out' class after adding a 200 ms delay to the fx queue. In other words, delay() will not pause items that are not added to a queue. Please see: [What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me) for more information about how jQuery queues work.

> $('.discrete').each(function() {
>       $(this).delay(200).addClass('out'); });

In the second example, you're adding the same timeout to each of the .discrete elements. So after roughly 200ms each one will have a class added to it at just about the same time. Instead you probably would have wanted to set a timeout of 200ms, then 400ms, then 600ms and so on for each element.

> $('.discrete').each(function() {    var theNode = $(this);
>   setTimeout(function() {
>          theNode.addClass('out');
>       }, 200); });

Answer (score 0):

## I have created simple 2 line solution which works among all frameworks

`let dl = 0.2; //time-delay
//                         <animation class>           <gap animation>
 document.querySelectorAll('.card.fade-in').forEach(o=>{dl+=0.2;o.style.animationDelay=dl+'s'});`