# Remove content form tag after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

after I get data and set them into tag, after 5 seconds I want to purge this tag. I try:

```
$('#ajax_message').html(data).delay(5000).html("");
```

But this doesnt work. How I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per doc:

> jQuery.delay() is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects and such, and is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

long story short, `.delay()` works for [queued functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096257/1719752). You should use `setTimeout()` instead.

```
$('#ajax_message').html(data)
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#ajax_message').html("");
},5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
     $('#ajax_message').html('');
}, 5000);
```

Comment: use `window.setTimeout()` if you want to execute once, `setInterval` will iterate each 5 second