# Promises in animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, promise

It has come to me the following query. Consider the next line of code:

```
case A: 
  $('#box').promise().done(function(){alert('Okay');});
```

In the above case, the alert message will be shown up immediately since `$('#box').promise()` will return a **resolved promise object** and the done callback will fire immediately. Now, if we change the above code to:

```
case B:   
  $('#box').hide(5000);
  $('#box').promise().done(function(){alert('Okay');});
```

the done callback will fire after 5 seconds. In that case I cannot find out **in which way jQuery recognizes** that $('#box') in the second line in case B is different from $('#box') in case A and knows that .hide() method is already applied on it as to correctly waiting for firing the callback. There must be some inner jQuery procedure...

Hope to be comprehensible.

Comment: It checks the element fx queue. If nothing in it, it resolves the deferred, otherwise wait for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There must be some inner jQuery procedure...

Yes, there is. The [animation queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058158/1048572) is attached to the DOM element using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), and will be retrieved by the call to [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) which defaults to await the animation queue. In your case A, it just happens to be empty, so that the promise is immediately fulfilled.

Comment: It appends it using `jQuery._data()` not `$.fn.data()` if i'm correct

Comment: @A.Wolff Correct, and I originally wanted to write "*using the same mechanism as `.data()`*" but found it too technical for this short and simple answer :-)

Comment: Is there any way to see the contents of the animation queue using .data() method on $('#box')?

Comment: @ILIAS: Not really, the animation queue (and other queues) are supposed to be private so that they don't collide with regular `.data()` usage. You might be able to see something using `$._data($('#box')[0], "fxqueue")` - otherwise, fire up your debugger and step through the `.promise()` call :-)